# How to use tikz matrix in a LaTeX command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, catcodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with defining shortcuts for TikZ matrices.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/problem-with-defining-shortcuts-for-tikz-matrices)

I tried to use a tikz Matrix in a LaTeX document as the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix{
    \node{a}; & \node{b}; \\
    \node{c}; & \node{d}; \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Everything is ok. But when I tried to use it in a LaTeX command as the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\Foo}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix{
    \node{a}; & \node{b}; \\
    \node{c}; & \node{d}; \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\Foo
\end{document}
```

It will report the following error:

```
!Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? thanks.

Comment: See [Problem with defining shortcuts for TikZ matrices.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/problem-with-defining-shortcuts-for-tikz-matrices) which seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with Martin.  This is a subtle issue with TikZ matrices and is tricky to figure out.  The question that Martin links to gives a way to solve it.  If that doesn't work for you, edit this question to explain why not; otherwise we'll close it as a duplicate of that one so that others with this question can more easily find an answer.

Comment: Yes, that solution solved this problem, please close this question, thanks.