# TikZ and subfigures in math nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

I have a tikzpicture with a matrix of math nodes. It by itself compiles fine. If I put it in a figure environment, it still compiles fine. However, if i put it in a subfigure environment, it returns that there is a `$` missing. Any ideas?

EDIT (@Werner): Here's something that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[something]{% <---- \subfloat begin
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=west}]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells]{
      \quad & 1.\quad (x)(Q\supset Fx) & \\
      & 2.\quad Q\supset Fx & \textrm{I,\textbf{UI}} & \\
      & 3.\quad Q \\
      & 4.\quad Fx & 2, 3, \textrm{ M.P.}\\
      & 5.\quad (x)Fx & 4, \textrm{ \textbf{UG}} \\
      & 6.\quad Q\supset(x)Fx & 3-5, \textrm{ C.P.} \\
      & 7.\quad \parbox[t]{2.9cm}{%
        $(x)(Q\supset(x)Fx)\supset$\\
        $[Q\supset(x)Fx]$} & 1-6, \textrm{ C.P.}\\};
    \draw[-stealth] (m-7-2.north east)
                 -| (m-1-1.west) |- (m-1-2);
    \draw[-stealth] (m-6-2.north east)
                 -| (m-3-1.east) |- (m-3-2);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}% <---- \subfloat end
\caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Try to wrap it in `{ .. }` or even `\hbox{ .. }`.

Comment: `\subfloat[something]{\scantokens{\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}\endinput}}` works. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you add the following to the preamble

`\newcommand{\Supset}{\ensuremath{\supset}}%`

and use `Supset` instead of `supset`, this error changes to

> Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.

See [Problem with defining shortcuts for TikZ matrices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/problem-with-defining-shortcuts-for-tikz-matrices) for more info on this issue.

So, to fix this, you could either use `\pgfmatrixnextcell` instead `&`, or `ampersand replacement=\&` option to `\matrix` (and then use `\&` instead of just `&`) which yields the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Supset}{\ensuremath{\supset}}%
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[something]{% <---- \subfloat begin
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=west}]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,ampersand replacement=\&]{
      \quad 
      \& 1.\quad (x)(Q\Supset Fx) \& \\
      \& 2.\quad Q\Supset Fx \& \textrm{I,\textbf{UI}} \& \\
      \& 3.\quad Q \\
      \& 4.\quad Fx \& 2, 3, \textrm{ M.P.}\\
      \& 5.\quad (x)Fx \& 4, \textrm{ \textbf{UG}} \\
      \& 6.\quad Q\Supset(x)Fx \& 3-5, \textrm{ C.P.} \\
      \& 7.\quad \mbox{\parbox[t]{2.9cm}{%
        $(x)(Q\Supset(x)Fx)\Supset$\\
        $[Q\Supset(x)Fx]$}} \& 1-6, \textrm{ C.P.}\\
};
    \draw[-stealth] (m-7-2.north east)
                 -| (m-1-1.west) |- (m-1-2);
    \draw[-stealth] (m-6-2.north east)
                 -| (m-3-1.east) |- (m-3-2);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}% <---- \subfloat end
\caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With the inclusion of `ampersand replacement=\&`, you don't need to use `\Supset`; you can revert back to the original `\supset`. Regardless, this (using a math matrix) seems like something that is basic in its functionality and avoids excessive use of math mode switches using `$`, yet requires a `&` -> `\&` work-around. Is this the only way?

Comment: Yep, it is possible to revert back but to just `supset`, but don't see the harm in just using `Supset`. It just feels "wrong" to use a math symbol like that without a `$..$` surrounding it, even though it appears that the symbols and text are in proper math font. Don't know if there are other workarounds, and I certainly would not want to use `\pgfmatrixnextcell`, but perhaps one of the `TikZ` experts here will elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to consider the `subcaption` package. This post has some good comparisons: [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig)

Below is an implementation using the `subcaption` package, and I didn't need to change your `TikZ` code at all :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=west}]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells]{
      \quad & 1.\quad (x)(Q\supset Fx) & \\
      & 2.\quad Q\supset Fx & \textrm{I,\textbf{UI}} & \\
      & 3.\quad Q \\
      & 4.\quad Fx & 2, 3, \textrm{ M.P.}\\
      & 5.\quad (x)Fx & 4, \textrm{ \textbf{UG}} \\
      & 6.\quad Q\supset(x)Fx & 3-5, \textrm{ C.P.} \\
      & 7.\quad \parbox[t]{2.9cm}{%
        $(x)(Q\supset(x)Fx)\supset$\\
        $[Q\supset(x)Fx]$} & 1-6, \textrm{ C.P.}\\};
    \draw[-stealth] (m-7-2.north east)
                 -| (m-1-1.west) |- (m-1-2);
    \draw[-stealth] (m-6-2.north east)
                 -| (m-3-1.east) |- (m-3-2);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \caption{Subcaption goes here}
 \end{subfigure}
\caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]