# Passing a TikZ matrix to a TeX macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, catcodes

When I pass code containing a TikZ matrix to a TeX macro it prints the following error message: `! Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\identity#1{#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \identity{
        \matrix {
            \node {1}; & \node{2};\\
            \node {3}; & \node{4};\\
        };
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why does this happen? Is there any way to make this work?

---

Rationale:

*I use such macros to create exercise sheets for my students. I like the answers to be embedded in the source code but naturally do not want them to show up on the exercise sheet. Thus I mark up my code with macros like `\problem{}` and `\answer{}` which are then suitably defined in the document header depending on whether I want to compile the exercise sheet or the reference solution.*

*The probably best way (I guess) would be to replace my markup macros with environments that use `\iftrue` or `\iffalse` to include or skip parts of the document, but currently I'm not ready to convert all my files. That's why I'm looking for a short term solution to that problem (that, and I'm curious).*

Comment: Very related: [Problem with defining shortcuts for TikZ matrices.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1111/2975)

Comment: Also: [Unknown error using tikz matrix of nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15093/2975)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Obviously I failed quite horribly at googling. :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the pgf manual:

> 17.5 Considerations Concerning Active Characters
>
> Even though `TikZ` seems to use `&` to separate cells, `pgf` actually uses a different
>   command to separate cells, namely the command `\pgfmatrixnextcell` and
>   using a normal `&` character will normally fail. What happens is that,
>   `TikZ` makes `&` an active character and then defines this character to
>   be equal to `\pgfmatrixnextcell`. In most situations this will work
>   nicely, but sometimes `&` cannot be made active; for instance because
>   the matrix is used in an argument of some macro or the matrix contains
>   nodes that contain normal `tabular` environments. In this case you can
>   use the following option to avoid having to type `\pgfmatrixnextcell`
>   each time:
>
> `/tikz/ampersand replacement= <macro name or empty>`

So the solution is to use `\pgfmatrixnextcell` instead of the usual `&` or to use an `ampersand replacement`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\identity#1{#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \identity{
        \matrix[ampersand replacement=\&] {
            \node {1}; \& \node{2};\\
            \node {3}; \& \node{4};\\
        };
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```