# Error related to tikz-cd and user-defined commands

Tags: macros, tikz-cd, tikz-matrix

My LaTeX document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\commSq}[8]
{
    \begin{tikzcd}
        #1 \ar[r, "#2"] \ar[d, "#6"] & #3 \ar[d,"#4"] \\
        #7 \ar[r, "#8"] & #5
    \end{tikzcd}
}

\begin{document}
%1
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar[r, "f"] \ar[d, "g"] & B \ar[d,"h"] \\
    C \ar[r, "i"] & D
\end{tikzcd}
%2
\commSq{A}{f}{B}{h}{D}{g}{C}{i}
\end{document}
```

I figured that the part the code below `%1` and the code below `%2` do the same thing. However, using the command `\commSq` instead yields the error `"Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode. [...]"` and I get this output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That is a very interesting question with a very clear and concise MWE. Thank you very much.

Comment: [“Single ampersand used with wrong catcode” error using tikz matrix in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15093/35864) made me think that using `\pgfmatrixnextcell` instead of `&` might work, and so it does. Hence, your question pretty much seems to be a duplicate of [Problem with defining shortcuts for TikZ matrices.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1111/35864).

Comment: @moewe Thank you! That works. I'm still confused though, about what user-defined commands have to do with tikz-matrices.

Comment: Well the OP in the other question also had problems with a `\newcommand` containing TikZ code. They did not use the `tikz-cd` package, but `tikz-cd` uses TikZ, so the issue is inherited, if you will.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I understand.