# TikZ node newcommand : pass color as argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, nodes

I need to create a row of circles (colored markers) followed by some text. See the image below.

[image]

I achieve this using the following code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\matrix[nodes={minimum width=0.05cm, minimum height=0.05cm},
 row sep=0.001cm, column sep=0.1cm] {
 \node[circle, fill=red ] {}; & 
 \node[circle, fill=blue ] {}; & 
 \node[circle, fill=green ] {}; & 
 \node[circle, fill=orange ] {}; & 
 \node[circle, fill=pink ] {}; & 
 \node[draw=none, fill=none, text width=4cm]{Some Text};\\}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Since I need to produce this output repetitively, I thought of defining a new command with the code above. Here's the command I defined.

```
\newcommand{\MarkersAndText}{6}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \matrix[nodes={minimum width=0.05cm, minimum height=0.05cm},
        row sep=0.001cm, column sep=0.1cm] {
    \node[circle, fill=#1] {}; &  
    \node[circle, fill=#2] {}; &  
    \node[circle, fill=#3] {}; & 
    \node[circle, fill=#4] {}; & 
    \node[circle, fill=#5] {}; & 
    \node[draw=none, fill=none, text width=4cm]{#6};\\}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, I get the following error,

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \tikz@temp. <to be read again> 1 l.19 \node[circle, fill=#1] {}; &
```

Can anyone help me to understand how I can resolve this problem?

Edit : David Carlisle's answer solves the error above. The compilation produces another error when I use the command `\MarkersAndText`. The new error is,

`Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode`

The error is fixed by changing the code block as,

`\matrix[nodes={minimum width=0.05cm, minimum height=0.05cm},
    row sep=0.001cm, column sep=0.1cm, ampersand replacement=\&] {
        \node[circle, fill=#1] {}; \&`

I am curious as to why the code without ampersand replacement works when outside `\newcommand`.

Comment: I hope this question helps your curiosity: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/problem-with-defining-shortcuts-for-tikz-matrices/1114#1114

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have a follow up question with the above setup but for a slightly different problem should I edit the question here? or ask a new question?

Comment: I think it is better to make a new question with a link to this one. If you edit this one, David's answer won't fit it.

Comment: Igansi's comment above is on point. I would like to know how one can pass a color as an argument to tkzstyle. I don't understand the solution posted here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\MarkersAndText}{6}
```

should be

```
\newcommand{\MarkersAndText}[6]
```

As it was you were defining `\MarkersAndText` to be `6`