# Use & inside commands

Tags: macros

Using [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611535/116348) I managed to create a function `\zx{A & B}` that can accepts the `&` char (to give to some sort of tikz matrices, as I would prefer to avoid using `\&` instead of `&`... Note that the error arrives even without using tikz at all). It works great... except in the `align` environment. In that case even `\zx{A}` (without using any `&`) breaks. Any idea how I could solve this issue?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand\zx{%
  \begingroup% To avoid ampersand issues https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611535/116348
  \NewDocumentCommand{\tmpZX}{O{}+m}{%
    \endgroup%
    \begin{tikzcd}[##1] ##2 \end{tikzcd}
    % Problem is not specific to tikzcd, and also appear if you use instead:
    % Hello (##1) ##2 :)
    % But just make sure to remove & and \rar since they only make sense in tikzcd.
  }%
  \catcode`&=13%
  \tmpZX%
}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Level 1: without inside.}

Works:
Hello \zx{A} and \zx{A \rar & B}.

\noindent Works:
\begin{equation}
  \zx{A} = \zx{A \rar & B}
\end{equation}

\noindent Fails:
% \begin{align}
%   \zx{A}
% \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `align` grabs its body as an argument so catcode changes can not work, you need to make them before you start the align

Comment: Oh, really? That's annoying... And I guess I can't change them document-wise without breaking other features... Also, do you mean that if an environment is based on Environ, it will also not work?

Comment: yes enviorn would be the same, that's why tikz offers the `\&` alternative.

Comment: Ok I see thanks... Too bad there is no alternative.

Comment: there is always an alternative, you could re-scan with`\scantokens` (but that is a tricky command to get right) or use some custom macro to look for a normal & and replace by an active one or ...   but using `\&` is not so bad and by far the least likely to break everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to make indirections:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand{\zx}{O{}+m}{%
  \begingroup\catcode`\&=\active
  \begin{tikzcd}[#1] \scantokens{#2} \end{tikzcd}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Hello \zx{A} and \zx{A \rar & B}.

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{equation}
  \zx{A} = \zx{A \rar & B}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1][4-6]
\begin{align}
  \zx{A} &= \zx{A \rar & B} \\
  x &= y
\end{align}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see from the last example, the `&` works in either case, both in and out of `\zx`.

In a slightly different (and more robust) way:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zx}{O{}+m}{%
  \tl_rescan:nn { \char_set_catcode_active:N \& } { \begin{tikzcd}[#1] #2 \end{tikzcd} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Hello \zx{A} and \zx{A \rar & B}.

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{equation}
  \zx{A} = \zx{A \rar & B}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1][4-6]
\begin{align}
  \zx{A} &= \zx{A \rar & B} \\
  x &= y
\end{align}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know why I missed the notification... I'm curious, how does this compare to the solution `\regex_replace_all` that you proposed here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633066/116348 ?

Comment: By the way, I'm realizing this code is evaluated twice when inserted inside an align environment... Any idea why? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633142/rescan-evaluated-twice-in-a-align

Answer (score 3):

If you like a complicated way without `\scantokens`, I can offer a macro-mechanism
`\ReplaceAnd{⟨replacement for &4⟩}⁠{⟨tokens where &4 shall be replaced by ⟨replacement for &4⟩⟩}`
which is driven by `\romannumeral`-expansion and which recursively replaces explicit `&`-character-tokens of category 4 (alignment tab).

As a side-effect any matching pair of explicit character tokens of category 1(begin group) and 2(end group) in *⟨tokens where &<sub>4</sub> shall be replaced by ⟨replacement for &<sub>4</sub>⟩⟩* is replaced by a matching pair of explicit character-tokens `{1` and `}2`.
As usually `{` and `}` are the only characters with category code 1 respective 2, this usually doesn't matter.

Active-& can be used as *⟨replacement for &<sub>4</sub>⟩*.
The tokens forming the `tikzcd`-environment can be used as *⟨tokens where &<sub>4</sub> shall be replaced by ⟨replacement for &<sub>4</sub>⟩⟩*.

```latex
\errorcontextlines=10000
\makeatletter
%%///////// Code for \ReplaceAnd //////////////////////////////////////////////
%% Syntax:
%% -------
%%
%% \ReplaceAnd{<replacement for &>}%
%%            {<tokens where & shall be replaced by <replacement for &>>}%
%%
%% The result is delivered after two expansion-steps/by two "hits"
%% with \expandafter.
%%
%% As a side-effect any matching pair of explicit character tokens 
%% of category code 1 and 2 is replaced by a matching pair of
%% explicit character-tokens {_1 and }_2.
%%
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange,
%% \UD@removespace, \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace, \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace,
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@removespace{\UD@Exchange{ }{\def\UD@removespace}{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only spaces):
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}{}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is a catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has a leading
%%                        explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked does not have a
%%                        leading explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with a space-token
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does have a
%%                                       leading explicit space-token>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does not have a
%%                                       a leading explicit space-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign/
    % tabular-environment:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
      \string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB.#1 }{}%
    }{}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB{%
  \long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB#1 {%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
    {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
     \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%.............................................................................
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{ABCDE} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{{AB}CDE} yields  {{AB}}
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result is delivered after two 
%% expansion-steps/after "hitting" \UD@ExtractFirstArg with \expandafter
%% twice.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument must not be blank.
%% This case can be cranked out via \UD@CheckWhetherBlank before calling
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg.
%%
%% Use frozen-\relax as delimiter for speeding things up.
%% Frozen-\relax is chosen because David Carlisle pointed out in
%% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
  {\long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1#2}{{#1}}%
}%
\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter
  \UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\romannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  }{%
    \UD@stopromannumeral\romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
  }%
}{%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArg[1]%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%====================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@AndInstance{\long\def\UD@AndInstance#1&#2#3!{#2}}%
\newcommand\UD@ReplaceAndInstance[2]{%
  % #1 a single token to examine
  % #2 replacement for &
  \UD@AndInstance#1{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}&{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}!%
}%
\newcommand\UD@AndReplaceloop[3]{%
  % #1 replacement for &
  % #2 tokens forming the result gathered so far
  % #3 remaining token list to process
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{%
    \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{#3}{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
        \expandafter{\UD@removespace#3}{\UD@stopromannumeral{#2 }}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#3}{%
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
            \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
              \romannumeral
              \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#3}{%
                \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\expandafter{\romannumeral
                  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
                  \UD@ExtractFirstArg{#3}{\UD@AndReplaceloop{#1}{}}%
                }%
              }{%
                \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@ReplaceAndInstance
                \UD@ExtractFirstArg{#3}{#1}%
              }%
            }%
            {#2}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }{\UD@AndReplaceloop{#1}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\ReplaceAnd[2]{%
  % #1 replacement for &
  % #2 tokens where to replace & by replacement for &
  \romannumeral\UD@AndReplaceloop{#1}{}{#2}%
}%
%%///////// End of code for \ReplaceAnd //////////////////////////////////////
\makeatother

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\&=13 %
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand{\zx}{o+m}{%
    \ReplaceAnd{&}{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\begin{tikzcd}}{\begin{tikzcd}[{#1}]}#2\end{tikzcd}}%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\subsection{Level 1: without inside.}

Works:
Hello \zx{A} and \zx{A \rar & B}.

\noindent Works:
\begin{equation}
  \zx{A} = \zx{A \rar & B}
\end{equation}

\noindent Works:
\begin{align}
  \zx{A} &= \zx{A \rar & B}\\
  \zx{UV} &= \zx{UV \rar & UW}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In case you like edge cases and weird scenarios:

Unlike the `\scantokens`-method the `\ReplaceAnd`-method does not double hashes and does not produce spaces behind control-word-tokens—here is an example where both the replacement-method and the `\scantokens`-method are combined so that you can see the subtle differences in edge cases:

```latex
\errorcontextlines=10000
\makeatletter
%%///////// Code for \ReplaceAND //////////////////////////////////////////////
%% Syntax:
%% -------
%%
%% \ReplaceAnd{<replacement for &>}%
%%            {<tokens where & shall be replaced by <replacement for &>>}%
%%
%% The result is delivered after two expansion-steps/by two "hits"
%% with \expandafter.
%%
%% As a side-effect any matching pair of explicit character tokens 
%% of category code 1 and 2 is replaced by a matching pair of
%% explicit character-tokens {_1 and }_2.
%%
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange,
%% \UD@removespace, \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace, \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace,
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@removespace{\UD@Exchange{ }{\def\UD@removespace}{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only spaces):
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}{}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is a catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has a leading
%%                        explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked does not have a
%%                        leading explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with a space-token
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does have a
%%                                       leading explicit space-token>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does not have a
%%                                       a leading explicit space-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign/
    % tabular-environment:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
      \string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB.#1 }{}%
    }{}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB{%
  \long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB#1 {%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
    {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
     \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%.............................................................................
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{ABCDE} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{{AB}CDE} yields  {{AB}}
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result is delivered after two 
%% expansion-steps/after "hitting" \UD@ExtractFirstArg with \expandafter
%% twice.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument must not be blank.
%% This case can be cranked out via \UD@CheckWhetherBlank before calling
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg.
%%
%% Use frozen-\relax as delimiter for speeding things up.
%% Frozen-\relax is chosen because David Carlisle pointed out in
%% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
  {\long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1#2}{{#1}}%
}%
\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter
  \UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\romannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  }{%
    \UD@stopromannumeral\romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
  }%
}{%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArg[1]%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%====================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@AndInstance{\long\def\UD@AndInstance#1&#2#3!{#2}}%
\newcommand\UD@ReplaceAndInstance[2]{%
  % #1 a single token to examine
  % #2 replacement for &
  \UD@AndInstance#1{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}&{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}!%
}%
\newcommand\UD@AndReplaceloop[3]{%
  % #1 replacement for &
  % #2 tokens forming the result gathered so far
  % #3 remaining token list to process
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{%
    \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{#3}{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
        \expandafter{\UD@removespace#3}{\UD@stopromannumeral{#2 }}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#3}{%
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
            \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
              \romannumeral
              \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#3}{%
                \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\expandafter{\romannumeral
                  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
                  \UD@ExtractFirstArg{#3}{\UD@AndReplaceloop{#1}{}}%
                }%
              }{%
                \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@ReplaceAndInstance
                \UD@ExtractFirstArg{#3}{#1}%
              }%
            }%
            {#2}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }{\UD@AndReplaceloop{#1}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\ReplaceAnd[2]{%
  % #1 replacement for &
  % #2 tokens where to replace & by replacement for &
  \romannumeral\UD@AndReplaceloop{#1}{}{#2}%
}%
%%///////// End of code for \ReplaceAnd //////////////////////////////////////
\makeatother

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\&=13 %
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand{\zx}{o+m}{%
    \ReplaceAnd{&}{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\begin{tikzcd}}{\begin{tikzcd}[{#1}]}#2\end{tikzcd}}%
  }%
}%


\NewDocumentCommand{\zxE}{O{}+m}{%
  \begingroup\catcode`\&=\active
  \begin{tikzcd}[#1]\scantokens{#2}\end{tikzcd}%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Q{\futurelet\QQ\QQQ}
\newcommand\QQQ{%
  \text{\texttt{\string\Q}(\ifx\QQ\@sptoken\else no \fi space token behind \texttt{\string\Q})}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent\verb|\ReplaceAnd|-method:

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{align}
  \zx{\string#A}&=\zx{\string#A \rar & \string#B}\\
  \zx{\catcode`\Q=12 \Q!}&=\zx{UV \rar & UW}
\end{align}
\end{verbatim}

\begin{align}
  \zx{\string#A}&=\zx{\string#A \rar & \string#B}\\
  \zx{\catcode`\Q=12 \Q!}&=\zx{UV \rar & UW}
\end{align}

\noindent\hrule\hfill\bigskip

\noindent\verb|\scantokens|-method:

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{align}
  \zxE{\string#A}&=\zxE{\string#A \rar & \string#B}\\
  \zxE{\catcode`\Q=12 \Q!}&=\zxE{UV \rar & UW}
\end{align}
\end{verbatim}


\begin{align}
  \text{You get: ! You can't use `macro paramete}&\text{r character \string#' in math mode.}\\
  %\zxE{\string#A}&=\zxE{\string#A \rar & \string#B}\\
  \zxE{\catcode`\Q=12 \Q!}&=\zxE{UV \rar & UW}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

About the coming-into-being of the rather unexpected effects/results with the `\scantokens`-method in those edge-cases/weird scenarios:

Section "3.7 Input Handling" of the [eTeX-manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/etex/etex_man.pdf) says about `\scantokens`:

> The command `\scantokens{...}` absorbs a list of unexpanded tokens,
> converts it into a character string that is treated as if it were an
> external file, and starts to read from this ‘pseudo-file’.
> [...]
> In particular every occurrence of the current newline character is
> interpreted as start of a new line, and input characters will be
> converted into tokens as usual.
> [...]

The crucial point hereby is the phrase "converts it into a character string". This conversion is done by **faking the unexpanded writing of the list of tokens** and treating the resulting characters (not tokens!) as if they would form an external file whose characters are to be read and pre-processed linewise as usual by TeX's eyes (removal of all space-characters that occur at right ends of lines, appending a character whose code point number in TeX's internal character encoding scheme equals the value of the integer-parameter `\endlinechar`) and where the characters that form the result of that pre-processing get tokenized by TeX's mouth on demand, i.e., whenever more tokens are needed by the gullet (where expansion is done) and/or by the stomach (where assignments take place and boxes/pages are build etc).

TeX doubles explicit character-tokens of category 6(parameter), i.e., hashes(`#`), when writing them to file unexpanded.

Apart from that "hash-doubling" the unexpanded-writing of a token is like applying `\string` to that token and writing the resulting sequence of unexpandable character-tokens and, in case the token in question is a control-word-token, appending a space-character. (In case the token in question is a control-symbol-token or an explicit character-token no space-character is appended.)

Applying `\string` with control-sequence-tokens in turn implies delivering a preceding escape-character whose code-point-number in TeX's internal character-representation-scheme equals the value of the integer-parameter `\escapechar`. Usually that value is 92, denoting the backslash, but it can be changed! As a special case applying `\string` to the nameless control-sequence, which comes into being by expanding `\csname\endcsname` or by placing a backslash at the end of a line of .tex-input while `\endlinechar` has a non-positive value, delivers `⟨character according to \escapechar⟩⁠csname⟨character according to \escapechar⟩endcsname`, no space character being appended.

All these things can bite you when applying `\scantokens`.

E.g., with `\zxE{\string#A}` the hash-doubling of  `\scantokens`  at the time of "writing the pseudo-file" leads to hashes in the sequence `\string#A` being doubled and space-characters being appended to things that come from unexpanded-writing control-word-tokens so that the pseudo-file that is to be processed as usual contains the characters
`\string⟨space-character⟩##A`.

This is taken for a file. Reading and pre-processing the first line of that file yields the characters
`\string⟨space-character⟩##A⟨character according to \endlinechar⟩`.

Tokenization yields the control-word-token `\string`. As TeX's reading-apparatus switches to state S(skipping blanks) after tokenizing a control-word-token, the subsequent *⟨space-character⟩* is just skipped and doesn't yield any token at all. Then the first hash is tokenized and yields an explicit `#`-character-token of category 6(parameter).  `\string` is applied to that character-token, which in turn yields an explicit `#`-character-token of category 12(other). This goes to the stomach and is typeset as any ordinary character is typeset in math-mode. Then the second hash is tokenized and yields an explicit `#`-character-token of category 6(parameter). This passes the gullet and reaches the stomach and causes a "! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode."-error.

With `` \zxE{\catcode`\Q=12 \Q!} `` `\scantokens`' creation of the pseudo-file leads to the pseudo-file consisting of the characters:

`` \catcode⟨space-character⟩`\Q⟨space-character⟩=12 \Q⟨space-character⟩! ``

Reading and pre-processing the first line of that file yields the characters

`` \catcode⟨space-character⟩`\Q⟨space-character⟩=12 \Q⟨space-character⟩!⟨character according to \endlinechar⟩ ``

When tokenizing these characters by and by and processing the resulting tokens, the character `\Q` gets assigned the category-code 12(other). Thus the last `\Q` is a control-symbol-token, not a control-word-token. As it is not a control-word-token, the reading-apparatus is not switched to state S(skipping blanks) but to state M(middle of line) and the subsequent *⟨space-character⟩* is not skipped but yields an explicit character-token of category code 10(space) and character-code 32. This in turn is detected by the `\futurelet`-mechanism underlying the definition of `\Q`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, I'm not sure why but I did not saw the notification... This looks really interesting, but oh, not simple, I'll need some time to digest it ^^  Also, I'm curious, how does it compare to the `  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \& } { \cA\& }` solution proposed here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633066/116348 ?

Comment: @tobiasBora Looks the same in this use case, except that this one is expandable so would be asymptotically slower; on the other hand regex has lots of overhead so this may actually be faster in practice.