# Resolving tikzcd/externalize/align incompatibilities

Tags: align, tikz-cd, tikz-external, catcodes, ampersand

I've been trying to follow the insights from the following posts:

- [Are the TikZ libraries cd and external incompatible with one another?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171931/are-the-tikz-libraries-cd-and-external-incompatible-with-one-another)
- [How to avoid redefining ampersand & globally?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/632643/148934)
- [Use & inside commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/619960/148934)

(The user tobiasBora seems to be interested in achieving very similar things to me.) However, I've ended up in a jumble of nothing quite working in all possible cases.

In short, I want to use a tikzcd environment that

- works as you would expect it to (duh!)
- also works in conjunction with the externalize package
- also works if you want to embed it in an amsmath align environment
- works with the beamer document class

My current attempt is in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse,etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,external}
%we don't actually need externalisation to demonstrate the problem, so turn it off for now
%\tikzexternalize

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{quantikz}{O{}+b}{%
   %local redefinition of catcode
  \begingroup \catcode`&=\active
  \def\@temp{\tikzcd@[#1]\scantokens{#2}}%
  \expandafter\@temp\endtikzcd\endgroup
}{}

%replace commands with environment. seems to help with externalize.
\patchcmd\tikzcd@{\tikzpicture}{\begin{tikzpicture}}{}{}
\patchcmd\endtikzcd{\endtikzpicture}{\end{tikzpicture}}{}{}

\makeatother

\tikzcdset{nodes in empty cells}

%this works
%also works with external switched on
%also works when documentclass is beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
H & \ar[l] 
\end{quantikz}

%this does not work
%neither does ampersand replacement
% \begin{align*}
% \begin{quantikz}
% & \ar[l] 
% \end{quantikz}
% \end{align*}

%original environment works with ampersand replacement
%but does not externalize
\begin{align*}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
 H \& \ar[l] 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I had wondered if a simple solution would be to get ampersand replacement working again within the new environment. But even if I directly replace all instances of & with \pgfmatrixnextcell, the quantikz environment doesn't seem to work inside align.

Comment: The `align` environment grabs its content at this point the catcode of `&` is fixed and you can't unfix it easily. (Though, we could possibly write a new `tikzcd` environment that takes its content and replaced all `&` with `\pgfmatrixnextcell`.) Are you actually using the `align*` environment with alignment? With your example, just using `equation*` would be enough.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, I'm actually using it for alignment, but was being minimal in my MWE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a defintion of `quantikz` that grabs the body and replaces every `&` in it with a `\pgfmatrixnextcell`.

Then, it places a `tikzpicture` environment in a way that the `external` accepts it (having `\end{tikzpicture}` not hidden in another macro) and disables the `tikzpicture` environment inside `tikzcd`. For this the options to `\tikzcd` (`\begin{tikzcd}`) will be moved to the `tikzpicture` environment which is where it's usually placed anyway.

This does *not patch* the `tikzcd` environment in any regard but only provides a new `quantikz` environment which should work like the original `tikzcd` environment but with `&` even inside an argument to a macro and with activated externalization.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, external}
\tikzexternalize
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{quantikz}{O{}+b}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[commutative~diagrams/.cd, every~diagram, #1]
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { & } { \pgfmatrixnextcell }
    \begingroup
      \def\tikzpicture[##1]{}
      \let\endtikzpicture\relax
      \tikzcd
        \l_tmpa_tl
      \endtikzcd
    \endgroup
  \end{tikzpicture}
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\tikzcdset{
  nodes in empty cells,
  diagrams={baseline=-axis_height}}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678935/16595
\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
H & \ar[l] 
\end{quantikz}

\begin{align*}
\left\{\begin{quantikz}
 H & \ar[l] X \\
 B \ar[ur]
\end{quantikz}\right\}
& = \{ x + 2 \}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! At first test, it appears to work :) Now I just need to make sure I can integrate it with the rest of the project...

Comment: @DaftWullie Please do. Note that since AMSmath typesets stuff twice (once for measurement, once for real) every TikZ picture gets externalized twice. There should be a Q&A about this but I can't find it right now, at worst, it only wastes disk space, though.