# Token read/write turns # into ##

Tags: token-lists

When I try to write an input given by a user in a token list to a file, it turns `#` into `##`, so if a users wants to write `\def\hello#1{Hello #1!}`, instead of writing:

```
\def\hello#1{Hello #1!}
```

as expected I get:

```
\def \hello ##1{Hello ##1!}
```

Any idea how to make it work? Ideally I'd like to avoid asking the user to change their input.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\mytokens
\newwrite\myWrite

\NewDocumentCommand{\writeInFile}{m}{%
  \mytokens={#1}% We put the input in a token list (that token list might actually be populated by another script before)
  \immediate\openout\myWrite myfile.tex\relax% We open the output file
  \immediate\write\myWrite{\the\mytokens}% We write to the output file
  \immediate\closeout\myWrite% We close the file
}

\begin{document}

%% I don't want to change the syntax in this part of the document:
\writeInFile{\def\hello#1{Hello #1!}}
\input{myfile.tex}

\hello{Alice}
\hello{Bob}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I define the command with two arguments, the first being the file name.

You want to change the category code of `#` before reading.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newwrite\myWrite
\newtoks\mytokens

\newcommand{\writeInFile}{%
  \begingroup\catcode`\#=12 \writeInFileAux
}
\newcommand{\writeInFileAux}[2]{% #1 = file name, #2 = what to write
  \immediate\openout\myWrite #1\relax% We open the output file
  \mytokens={#2}%
  \immediate\write\myWrite{\the\mytokens}% We write to the output file
  \immediate\closeout\myWrite% We close the file
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

%% I don't want to change the syntax in this part of the document:
\writeInFile{\jobname-out}{\def\hello#1{Hello #1!}}
\input{\jobname-out}

\hello{Alice}
\hello{Bob}

\end{document}
```

This will be the written out file

```
\def \hello #1{Hello #1!}
```

Of course, you cannot have `\writeInFile` as the argument to another command.

You can remove this limitation by doing a string replacement.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \g_bora_write_iow
\str_new:N \l_bora_write_str

\NewDocumentCommand{\writeInFile}{mm}
 {
  % #1 = file name, #2 = what to write
  \str_set:Nn \l_bora_write_str { #2 }
  \str_replace_all:NnV \l_bora_write_str { ## } \c_hash_str
  \iow_open:Nn \g_bora_write_iow { #1 }
  \iow_now:NV \g_bora_write_iow \l_bora_write_str
  \iow_close:N \g_bora_write_iow
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_replace_all:Nnn { NnV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%% I don't want to change the syntax in this part of the document:
\textit{xx \writeInFile{\jobname-out}{\def\hello#1{Hello #1!}}}
\input{\jobname-out}

\hello{Alice}
\hello{Bob}

\end{document}
```

The `\textit` bit is just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Another solution to the frozen catcode issue would be to use \scantokens (if they're using etex) instead of replacing ##, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot! So string can actually contain token lists? I'm still confused however: how does it compare with `\scantokens/\tl_rescan`? I'm surprised that it seems to handle properly `&` in `align` without a need for `\tl_rescan` as you proposed here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619983/116348

Comment: @Slurp and egreg: I tried to use `\scantokns/tl_rescan` to also handle other characters (it might not make a difference for LaTeX documents, but it does in non-latex code) here, without success https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680240/put-in-a-latex3-string-the-exact-input-string-to-write-in-a-file