# Use \ldelim with tall rows

Tags: tables, delimiters

I would like to put a  brace in front of some table rows.
I found [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15274/13816) here and in [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15364/13816) the use of the `bigdelim` package is suggested.

The problem is, it does not seem to work if a row contains a lot of text that is wrapped to multiple lines. Here is an example to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ccl}
    \ldelim\{{3}{3mm}[a] & \ldelim\{{1}{3mm}[x] &
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
      \blindtext
    \end{minipage}\\
    &\ldelim\{{1}{3mm}[y] & More text\\
    &\ldelim\{{1}{3mm}[z] & More text
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:
[image: compiled example]

What I would like is to let the brace *x* span over all of the lorem ipsum text and the brace *a* to span over all three table rows.

How can I achieve this (using `\ldelim` is not a strict requirement, but I like the syntax)?

**EDIT:**
Note that the `minipage` I use to hold the text does not only need to contain text but also e.g. a `tikzpicture` or some small `tabular` (I'm not exactly sure yet…). So the `minipage`s height does not need to be a multiple of the height of a line of text.

Comment: `\ldelim` has an option that tells how many lines it should span, and right now it is set to use 3 lines. Change it to 13 and add `[t]` option to the minipage and it should work. (`\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}`). But I don't think a minipage solution is the right thing for you. Can you include your own case here?

Comment: @percusse Thanks! The [documentation](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/doc/multirow.pdf) describes the option as "…extends over the n **rows**…", so I didn't think about setting it to a higher number than I have rows in the table. See my edit to the question for why your solution does not work and why I would like to use the `minipage`. Any other ideas?

Comment: You can look at Gonzalo's solution from the same question too.

Comment: @percusse Thanks again! If possible I'd like to avoid specifying the braces height, it should always be "as tall as needed". But I think I'll give [Herberts answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15287/13816) a try (even if the syntax is a bit awkward, in my opinion), if no other solution pops up…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get most of this effect by using the `\left` and `\right` commands from mathmode. It's not a great solution though, as the horizontal alignment is not great. Then again, you might be able to just tweak it manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  $a \left\{\begin{array}{l}
    x \left\{\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth} \blindtext \end{minipage}\right.
    \\
    y\left\{\mbox{More text}\right.
    \\
    z\left\{\mbox{More text}\right.
  \end{array}\right.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works and does what I want, even though the syntax is a bit awkward in my opinion… :-P I'll accept this answer, if nothing else shows up ;-)