# Horizontal Braces over the latex table

Tags: tables, braces, overbrace, bigdelim

I am trying to put two braces in the top of table colomns as shown in the image below. I found a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117107/use-ldelim-with-tall-rows) and in an answer the use of the `bigdelim package`  is suggested.

I tried to use [overbrace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141934/overbrace-over-two-columns-of-3-column-table) but it didnt worked for me or I am not using it properly.

Here is an example to illustrate the problem:

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{cccccclccccl}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  {\overbrace\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Case study:1\\ (check 1)\end{tabular}}}} &
  {\overbrace\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Case study:2\\ (check 2)\end{tabular}}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Method} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Class} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{cat} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ball} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ali} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{micheal} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{tara} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{cat} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ball} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ali} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{micheal} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{tara} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{kk}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-12} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-12} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{T} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-12} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{Average:}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{cccccclccccl}
  & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Case study:1\\ (check 1)\end{tabular}}} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Case study:2\\ (check 2)\end{tabular}}} \\
  & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\downbracefill} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\downbracefill} \\
 \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Method} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Class} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{cat} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ball} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ali} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{micheal} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{tara} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{cat} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ball} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ali} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{micheal} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{tara} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{kk}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-12} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-12} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{T} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-12} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{Average:}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.4 of 2021-11-23).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{12}{c}}
\RowStyle[bold]{}
& & \Block{1-5}{Case study:1\\ (check 1)} &&&&&
\Block{1-5}{Case study: 2\\ (check 2)} \\
\\
\Block[hvlines]{*-*}{}
Method & Class & cat & ball & ali & micheal & tara & cat & ball & ali & micheal & tara \\
\Block{4-1}{kk} & R \\
                & C \\
                & T \\
                & \textbf{Average:} \\
\CodeAfter
  \OverBrace[yshift=1mm,shorten]{3-3}{3-7}{}
  \OverBrace[yshift=1mm,shorten]{3-8}{3-12}{}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]