# How to create the following matrix with grouping structure?

Tags: matrices

I want to write the following matrix in latex,

[image]

Adding the group structure is creating some problem. Can anyone provide me with a simple code to generate the groups for the matrices?

Thank you,

Prithish.

Comment: Please share with us what you have got so far. Provide a MWE (minimal working example) which starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Please, (i) see the last answer listed on the right of your question (as related questions) and try on it basis write code for your matrix. on this basis we can further help you to add curly braces on the right side of matrix.

Comment: possibly helpful: [How to write brackets in a matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234906/579)

Comment: Why didn't you try anything yourself and present it here?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that's uses nested `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\newcommand\curlygroup[1]{%
  \left.\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  \vphantom{x_11} \\ \vphantom{vdots} \\ \vphantom{x_11}
  \end{array}\right\} \text{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
x_{11}   & x_{12}  & \cdots & x_{1p} \\
\vdots   & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{k1}   & x_{k2}  & \cdots & x_{kp} \\
\hline
x_{k+1,1}&x_{k+1,2}& \cdots & x_{k+1,p}\\
\vdots   & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots   \\
x_{n1}   & x_{n2}  & \cdots & x_{np}   \\
\end{array}\right]
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
\curlygroup{Group 1}\\[4.5ex]
\curlygroup{Group 2}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin,last-col=5]
    x_{11}   & x_{12}  & \cdots & x_{1p} & \Block{3-1}{\quad \text{Group } 1} \\
    \vdots   & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
    x_{k1}   & x_{k2}  & \cdots & x_{kp} \\
    \hline
    x_{k+1,1}&x_{k+1,2}& \cdots & x_{k+1,p}& \Block{3-1}{\quad \text{Group } 2}\\
    \vdots   & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots   \\
    x_{n1}   & x_{n2}  & \cdots & x_{np}   \\
\CodeAfter [sub-matrix/xshift=2mm]
  \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{3-4}{\}}
  \SubMatrix{.}{4-1}{6-4}{\}}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]