# Multi-line delimiter alongside list environment and normal text paragraph

Tags: lists, delimiters

I would ask how to add a multi-line delimiter (e.g. curly brackets) inside a list environment, preferably little past margin. Also it will be useful to know how to add it alongside normal text paragraph.
I have managed to do it inside a tabular environment with the bigdelim package.

Edit: I'm trying to do it by defining a command that creates a brace (as seen here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15276/41963), and then positioning in the left margin with marginnote package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{array}

\newcommand\RBrace[2]{%
  \left.\rule{0pt}{#1}\text{#2}\right\{}


\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar 


  \begin{document}

  \begin{itemize}

  \item adsasd \marginnote{$\begin{array}{l}\RBrace{1.7cm}{1}\end{array}$\hspace*{-20pt}}

  \item asdas 

  \item fsdfd

  \item   dfgsbgbf

  \item asdaasd 

  \end{itemize}
```

[image]

The result is good for what I'm looking for, but I'm wondering if there is a more "conventional" way to obtain it.

Thank you

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise about your aim?

Comment: @egreg I edited the question adding code lines and an image of the output