# Adding a large brace next to a table: Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, braces

I have the following table in Beamer:

[image: Table]

> I would like to add a large curly brace "{" on the left of the table (outside) spanning the first three rows and add some information concerning these rows next to the brace. How do I achieve this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
\gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%
\gdef\beamer@notes{}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=10mm} 
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\small}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}{Text}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Column A & Column B\\
\hline \hline
Some text & Some text\\
Some text  & Some text\\
Some text &Some text \\
Some text & Some text\\
Some text & Some text\\
Some text & Some text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that very simply with the `bigdelim` package, which comes with `multirow`: it is enough to add a column on the left and  use the `\ldelimiter` command in tne leftmost cell of the relevant row:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
\gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%
\gdef\beamer@notes{}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=10mm}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\small}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{frame}{Text}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{r@{\,}|c|c|}
\cline{2-3}
 & Column A & Column B\\
\cline{2-3} \cline{2-3}
\color{red}\ldelim\{{3}{*}[\color{blue} Some info]& Some text & Some text\\
 & Some text & Some text\\
 & Some text &Some text \\
 & Some text & Some text\\
 & Some text & Some text\\
 & Some text & Some text\\
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you! Any way to change the color of the brace?

Comment: Yes, it is very simple: add the color command at the beginning of the cell containing `\ldelimiter`. You even can choose another colour for the text  (or use the default black). Please see the code in my updated answer.

Comment: @Bernard Hello, how can I write the "Some Info" in two lines instead of one?

Comment: @Wallflower: the simplest for me would be to use one of the `stackengine` commands, say `Shortunderstack[l]{Some \\ Info}`

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your reponse. I get the error Misplaced \cr. V

Comment: Did you load stackengine with the `[usestackEOL]` option?

Answer (score 0):

Proof of concept for adding braces and explanation on right side -- you have to delete or amend the line expressing textwidth for the table else table will occupy the entire frame

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{}%<----------remember to delete both braces at the end if 
                                       %using this solution
```

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
\gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%
\gdef\beamer@notes{}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=10mm} 
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\small}

\newcommand\MyLBrace[2]{%
  \left.\rule{0pt}{#1}\right\}\text{#2}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}{Text}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{c@{}l}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline
Column A \\
\hline \hline
Some text\\
Some text\\
Some text\\
Some text\\
Some textt\\
Some text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
&
  $\begin{array}{l}
    \MyLBrace{3ex}{things beginning with vowels} \\ 
    \MyLBrace{3ex}{things beginning with consonants} \\
    \MyLBrace{4.4ex}{things beginning and ending with t} 
  \end{array}$
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Solution given by @GonzaloMedina --- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15276/197451

Comment: I had already seen this but couldn't translate it to my situation!