# Is there a way to merge symbols in line position in tabularray in LaTeX?

Tags: tabularray

I want to merge two `}` in the picture below to become a big `}`. When I tried it with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{talltblr}[caption={test}]{
colspec={c c c},vline{2}={1-2}{text=\clap{\}}}
}
Hello&\SetCell[r=2]{m}Hello2&Hello4\\
Hello5&Hello6&Hello7\\
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}•
\end{document}
```

there were two `}`. Is there a way to merge two `}` to big one?

[image]

Comment: `multirow.sty` will be an another option...

Comment: A possible answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15276/260996

Comment: @MattD626 Thanks, that's a good way.

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thanks, it is a another way.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to know if what I'm going to suggest fits your actual use case, since I suspect there is more going on in your actual table than is shown in this example …

And this doesn't exactly merge anything in the tabularray, but it just seems easier to me, in order to do the big brace and match it to the size of those rows, if you put them in the same cell; you could use a tabular inside the tabularray to emulate the effect of having them in different rows:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{talltblr}[caption={test}]{
colspec={c c c}
}
\(\left.
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Hello\\[4pt]
Hello5
\end{tabular}
\right\}\)
&Hello2&
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Hello4\\[4pt]
Hello7
\end{tabular}
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
```

[image: brakces example 1]

But then it occurred to me that since it ended up being only one row, that there was really no reason for the longtblr at all …

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{another test}
\medskip\(\left.
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Hello\\[4pt]
Hello5
\end{tabular}
\right\}\)
\quad Hello2 \quad
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Hello4\\[4pt]
Hello7
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: braces example 2]

But without knowing exactly what your real use case is, this may not be appropriate at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way to resolve this in `tabularray` as it seems neater.

Comment: If you only want to use tabularray's environments and don't want to use a regular tabular environment on the inside, you can use `tblr` instead. Just replace `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}...\end{tabular}` with `\begin{tblr}{@{}Q[c,mode=text]@{}} .. \end{tblr}` in both places.

Comment: Okay, good idea. Thanks a lot!