# How to Specify two level row and column labels of a matrix by braces?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I'm trying to write the following matrices. 
[image]

I used the following code (given by [Caramdir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40/how-do-i-label-different-rows-or-columns-of-a-matrix-using-braces/1070#1070))

```
\documentclass{article}
% Load TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
% Set various styles for the matrices and braces. It might pay off to fiddle around     with the values a little bit
 \pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration=brace,every left delimiter/.style=    {xshift=3pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-3pt}}}
 \pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=[,right delimiter=    {]},inner sep=2pt,column sep=1em,row sep=0.5em,nodes={inner sep=0pt}}}
 \pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixbrace/.style={decorate,thick}}
 \newcommand\mymatrixbraceoffseth{0.5em}
 \newcommand\mymatrixbraceoffsetv{0.2em}

% Now the commands to produce the braces. (I'll explain below how to use them.)
\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceright[4][m]{
\draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(#1.north west)!(#1-#3-1.south west)!(#1.south west)-    (\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$)
    -- node[left=2pt] {#4} 
    ($(#1.north west)!(#1-#2-1.north west)!(#1.south west)-(\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);
}
 \newcommand*\mymatrixbraceleft[4][m]{
 \draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(#1.north east)!(#1-#2-1.north east)!(#1.south east)+    (\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$)
    -- node[right=2pt] {#4} 
     ($(#1.north east)!(#1-#3-1.south east)!(#1.south east)+    (\mymatrixbraceoffseth,0)$);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracetop[4][m]{
\draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(#1.north west)!(#1-1-#2.north west)!(#1.north east)+(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$)
    -- node[above=2pt] {#4} 
    ($(#1.north west)!(#1-1-#3.north east)!(#1.north east)+(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracebottom[4][m]{
\draw[mymatrixbrace] ($(#1.south west)!(#1-1-#3.south east)!(#1.south east)-(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$)
    -- node[below=2pt] {#4} 
    ($(#1.south west)!(#1-1-#2.south west)!(#1.south east)-(0,\mymatrixbraceoffsetv)$);
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}


 \[
 \begin{tikzpicture}[mymatrixenv]
 \matrix[mymatrix] (m)  {
    a & b & c & d & e & f \\
    g & h & i & j & k & l\\
    l & m & n & o & p & o \\
    \hline \\
    q & r & s & t & u & v \\
    w & x & y & z & a & b \\
    c & d & e & f & g & h \\
  };
  \mymatrixbraceright{1}{3}{$E_1$}
  \mymatrixbraceright{5}{7}{$E_2$}
  \mymatrixbracetop{1}{3}{$E_1$}
  \mymatrixbracetop{4}{6}{$E_2$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

It's really nice but still it doesn't serve my purpose. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is wrong with the code that Caramdir gave you?  What in particular do you want it to do?

Comment: @Andrew: I guess the `G_i`'s are missing. (Is it bad that I can't remember writing that code?)

Comment: @Caramidr: Well, that's easy enough to add to your code.  My simplest method is to use the `fit` library to shift the delimiters from the main matrix to a submatrix, then put the `G_i`s as the first row and column of the matrix.

Comment: Please don't repost an answer in your question. That only clutters the space and makes it harder to see what the question is.

Comment: @Caramidr: Sorry for posting my answer. Next time I'll take care of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my version. With some tweaking, it can be made efficient.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),row sep=0.5cm,column sep=0.5cm] (m) {
1&2&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4 \\};
\draw[dashed] ($0.5*(m-1-2.north east)+0.5*(m-1-3.north west)$) --
      ($0.5*(m-4-2.south east)+0.5*(m-4-3.south west)$);
\draw[dashed] ($0.5*(m-2-1.south west)+0.5*(m-3-1.north west)$) --
      ($0.5*(m-2-4.south east)+0.5*(m-3-4.north east)$);
\node[above=10pt of m-1-1] (top-1) {a};
\node[above=10pt of m-1-2] (top-2) {b};
\node[above=10pt of m-1-3] (top-3) {c};
\node[above=10pt of m-1-4] (top-4) {d};

\node[left=12pt of m-1-1] (left-1) {$\alpha$};
\node[left=12pt of m-2-1] (left-2) {$\beta$};
\node[left=12pt of m-3-1] (left-3) {$\gamma$};
\node[left=12pt of m-4-1] (left-4) {$\delta$};

\node[rectangle,above delimiter=\{] (del-top-1) at ($0.5*(top-1.south) +0.5*(top-2.south)$) {\tikz{\path (top-1.south west) rectangle (top-2.north east);}};
\node[above=10pt] at (del-top-1.north) {$A$};
\node[rectangle,above delimiter=\{] (del-top-2) at ($0.5*(top-3.south) +0.5*(top-4.south)$) {\tikz{\path (top-3.south west) rectangle (top-4.north east);}};
\node[above=10pt] at (del-top-2.north) {$B$};

\node[rectangle,left delimiter=\{] (del-left-1) at ($0.5*(left-1.east) +0.5*(left-2.east)$) {\tikz{\path (left-1.north east) rectangle (left-2.south west);}};
\node[left=10pt] at (del-left-1.west) {$C$};
\node[rectangle,left delimiter=\{] (del-left-2) at ($0.5*(left-3.east) +0.5*(left-4.east)$) {\tikz{\path (left-3.north east) rectangle (left-4.south west);}};
\node[left=10pt] at (del-left-2.west) {$D$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is

[image: matrix]

Answer to comment :
One way to incorporate the math signs is to place everything in nodes. You could also place the matrices within boxes and include them in an equation, but this approach is tricky and delicate. As an example, just insert the following code after my initial code, before the `\end{tikzpicture}` :

```
\node[right=of m] (op) {$\times$};

\matrix [right=of op,matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),row sep=0.5cm,column sep=0.5cm] (n) {
1&2 \\
1&2 \\
};

\node[above=10pt of n-1-1]  {a};
\node[above=10pt of n-1-2]  {b};

\node[left=12pt of n-1-1]  {$\alpha$};
\node[left=12pt of n-2-1]  {$\beta$};
```

Comment: Thanks Frederic. This works fine. I'd highly appreciate if you could help me on first matrix too. Thanks

Comment: @MYa Isn't the first matrix just the same without the braces (i.e. without the last two blocks of code)?

Comment: @MYa : As Caramdir writes in his comment, the first matrix is obtained from what I wrote by removing parts of the code : the last two blocks and the draw commands for the dashed lines.

Comment: I figured out all three matrices of the first part but but don't know how to connect them with equal and multiplication sign in one line. Thanks

Comment: @MYa. I added a solution to your last question in your comment.

Comment: You could also add several tikzpictures in a math environment. (with something like `[baseline=-0.7ex]` to keep them vertically centered).

Answer (score 3):

I have used the following code. It works well in the first Matrix, but it does not work for the second part of the Picture. I have a problem that matrices are overlapped and the equal sign and multiplication sign as well. 
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning}
 \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),row sep=0.5cm,column sep=0.5cm] (m) {
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\};

\draw[dashed] ($0.5*(m-1-3.north east)+0.5*(m-1-4.north west)$) --
     ($0.5*(m-6-4.south east)+0.5*(m-6-3.south west)$);

\draw[dashed] ($0.5*(m-3-1.south west)+0.5*(m-4-1.north west)$) --
 ($0.5*(m-3-6.south east)+0.5*(m-4-6.north east)$);

\node[above=10pt of m-1-1] (top-1) {$G_1$};
\node[above=10pt of m-1-2] (top-2) {$G_2$};
\node[above=10pt of m-1-3] (top-3) {$G_3$};
\node[above=10pt of m-1-4] (top-4) {$G_1$};
\node[above=10pt of m-1-5] (top-5) {$G_2$};
\node[above=10pt of m-1-6] (top-6) {$G_3$};

\node[left=12pt of m-1-1] (left-1) {$G_1$};
\node[left=12pt of m-2-1] (left-2) {$G_2$};
\node[left=12pt of m-3-1] (left-3) {$G_3$};
\node[left=12pt of m-4-1] (left-4) {$G_1$};
\node[left=12pt of m-5-1] (left-5) {$G_2$};
\node[left=12pt of m-6-1] (left-6) {$G_3$};

\node[rectangle,above delimiter=\{] (del-top-1) at ($0.5*(top-1.south) +0.5*(top-3.south)$) {\tikz{\path (top-1.south west) rectangle (top-3.north east);}};
\node[above=10pt] at (del-top-1.north) {$E_1$};
\node[rectangle,above delimiter=\{] (del-top-2) at ($0.5*(top-4.south) +0.5*(top-6.south)$) {\tikz{\path (top-4.south west) rectangle (top-6.north east);}};
\node[above=10pt] at (del-top-2.north) {$E_2$};

\node[rectangle,left delimiter=\{] (del-left-1) at ($0.5*(left-1.east) +0.5*(left-3.east)$) {\tikz{\path (left-1.north east) rectangle (left-3.south west);}};
\node[left=10pt] at (del-left-1.west) {$E_1$};
\node[rectangle,left delimiter=\{] (del-left-2) at ($0.5*(left-4.east) +0.5*(left-6.east)$) {\tikz{\path (left-4.north east) rectangle (left-6.south west);}};
\node[left=10pt] at (del-left-2.west) {$E_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),row sep=0.2cm,column sep=0.2cm] (g) {
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\};

\node[above=8pt of g-1-1] (top-1) {$G_1$};
\node[above=8pt of g-1-2] (top-2) {$G_2$};
\node[above=8pt of g-1-3] (top-3) {$G_3$};
\node[above=8pt of g-1-4] (top-4) {$G_1$};
\node[above=8pt of g-1-5] (top-5) {$G_2$};
\node[above=8pt of g-1-6] (top-6) {$G_3$};

\node[left=12pt of g-1-1] (left-1) {$G_1$};
\node[left=12pt of g-2-1] (left-2) {$G_2$};
\node[left=12pt of g-3-1] (left-3) {$G_3$};
\node[left=12pt of g-4-1] (left-4) {$G_1$};
\node[left=12pt of g-5-1] (left-5) {$G_2$};
\node[left=12pt of g-6-1] (left-6) {$G_3$};

\node[right=100pt of g-1-1] (right-1) {$G_1$};
\node[right=100pt of g-2-1] (right-2) {$G_2$};
\node[right=100pt of g-3-1] (right-3) {$G_3$};
\node[right=100pt of g-4-1] (right-4) {$G_1$};
\node[right=100pt of g-5-1] (right-5) {$G_2$};
\node[right=100pt of g-6-1] (right-6) {$G_3$};
\node[right=of g] (op) {$=$};


\matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),row sep=0.2cm,column sep=0.2cm] (m) {
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\};

\node[above=8pt of m-1-1] (top-1) {$G_1$};
\node[above=8pt of m-1-2] (top-2) {$G_2$};
\node[above=8pt of m-1-3] (top-3) {$G_3$};
\node[above=8pt of m-1-4] (top-4) {$G_1$};
\node[above=8pt of m-1-5] (top-5) {$G_2$};
\node[above=8pt of m-1-6] (top-6) {$G_3$};

\node[left=12pt of m-1-1] (left-1) {$G_1$};
\node[left=12pt of m-2-1] (left-2) {$G_2$};
\node[left=12pt of m-3-1] (left-3) {$G_3$};
\node[left=12pt of m-4-1] (left-4) {$G_1$};
\node[left=12pt of m-5-1] (left-5) {$G_2$};
\node[left=12pt of m-6-1] (left-6) {$G_3$};

\node[right=100pt of m-1-1] (right-1) {$G_1$};
\node[right=100pt of m-2-1] (right-2) {$G_2$};
\node[right=100pt of m-3-1] (right-3) {$G_3$};
\node[right=100pt of m-4-1] (right-4) {$G_1$};
\node[right=100pt of m-5-1] (right-5) {$G_2$};
\node[right=100pt of m-6-1] (right-6) {$G_3$};
\node[right=of m] (op) {$\times$};

    \matrix [right=of op,matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),row sep=0.2cm,column sep=0.2cm] (n) {
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\
1&2&3&4&3&4 \\};

\node[above=8pt of n-1-1]  {$G_1$};
\node[above=8pt of n-1-2]  {$G_2$};
\node[above=8pt of n-1-3]  {$G_3$};
\node[above=8pt of n-1-4]  {$G_1$};
\node[above=8pt of n-1-5]  {$G_2$};
\node[above=8pt of n-1-6]  {$G_3$};

\node[left=12pt of n-1-1]  {$G_1$};
\node[left=12pt of n-2-1]  {$G_2$};
\node[left=12pt of n-3-1]  {$G_3$};
\node[left=12pt of n-4-1]  {$G_1$};
\node[left=12pt of n-5-1]  {$G_2$};
\node[left=12pt of n-6-1]  {$G_3$};

\node[right=100pt of n-1-1]  {$G_1$};
\node[right=100pt of n-2-1]  {$G_2$};
\node[right=100pt of n-3-1]  {$G_3$};
\node[right=100pt of n-4-1]  {$G_1$};
\node[right=100pt of n-5-1]  {$G_2$};
\node[right=100pt of n-6-1]  {$G_3$};

\end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user4898: I also got the similar problem.

Comment: You name both the nodes equal sign and the times `(op)`, which will naturally confuse TikZ. You should name the equal sign node something else (like `(eq)`). Also the matrix after the the equal sign is missing the `right=of eq` (or similar).

Comment: @Frederic and @Caramdir: Thanks a lot. Eventually I got for what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Why matrix is floating to the right of the page?

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix` (you need several compilations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

$\begin{NiceArray}[margin]{cc*{4}{w{c}{4mm}}}
               &        & \Block{1-2}{A} && \Block{1-2}{B} \\
               &        & a & b & a & b \\
\Block{2-1}{C} & \alpha & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
               & \beta  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\Block{2-1}{D} & \gamma & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
               & \delta & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix({3-3}{6-6})[vlines=2,hlines=2]
  \OverBrace[shorten]{2-3}{2-4}{}
  \OverBrace[shorten]{2-5}{2-6}{}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{3-2}{4-2}{.}[extra-height=-1mm]
  \SubMatrix{\{}{5-2}{6-2}{.}[extra-height=-1mm]
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If you prefer dashed rules, you can draw them with Tikz (and the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

$\begin{NiceArray}[margin]{cc*{4}{w{c}{4mm}}}
               &        & \Block{1-2}{A} && \Block{1-2}{B} \\
               &        & a & b & a & b \\
\Block{2-1}{C} & \alpha & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
               & \beta  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\Block{2-1}{D} & \gamma & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
               & \delta & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix({3-3}{6-6})
  \OverBrace[shorten]{2-3}{2-4}{}
  \OverBrace[shorten]{2-5}{2-6}{}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{3-2}{4-2}{.}[extra-height=-1mm]
  \SubMatrix{\{}{5-2}{6-2}{.}[extra-height=-1mm]
  \tikz \draw [dashed,shorten < = 2mm] (5-|3) -- (5-|7) ;
  \tikz \draw [dashed,shorten < = 1mm, shorten > = 1mm] (3-|5) -- (7-|5) ;
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]