# How can I add clips above matrix?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bar{P}=
\kbordermatrix{ \mathrm{state} &   1 &   2 &   4 &   3 &   6 &   5 &   7 \\
                             1 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.6 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                             2 & 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.7 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                             4 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                             3 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                             6 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.7 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                             5 & 0.0 & 0.4 & 0.1 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
                             7 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.5}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This generates a nice matrix:

[image]

How can I add clips above column descriptions as shown in image below?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are ready to use TikZ, you can take a look at this question  [two level matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15825/how-to-specify-two-level-row-and-column-labels-of-a-matrix-by-braces/15851#15851)

or you can look at the following code:

```
\documentclass{mwrep}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\bar{P}=
\bordermatrix{ \mathrm{state} &   \tikzmark{left}{1} &   \tikzmark{right}{2}  \cr
                             1 & 0.3 & 0.1  \cr
                             2 & 0.3 & 0.2}
\end{equation}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[decoration=brace,decorate,blue] (left.north west) -- (right.north east) node[midway,above=3pt] {$s_1$};}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: I like this solution as much as David's one, but try to compile it with text above equation.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\hmmA{\noalign{\global\let\@kbrowstyle\scriptstyle}}
\def\hmmB{\noalign{\kern.2ex\global\let\@kbrowstyle\relax}}
\setlength{\kbrowsep}{20pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}



\begin{equation}
\bar{P}=
\kbordermatrix{
  &\multispan3\hfill$\scriptstyle S_1$\hfill&
   \multispan2\hfill$\scriptstyle S_2$\hfill&
  & \\
  \noalign{\kern-\kbrowsep\kern-.2ex}
  &\multispan3\quad\downbracefill\quad&
   \multispan2\quad\downbracefill\quad&  & \\
\hmmA
\mathrm{state} &   1 &   2 &   4 &   3 &   6 &   5 &   7 \\
\hmmB
                             1 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.6 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                             2 & 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.7 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                             4 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                             3 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                             6 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.7 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                             5 & 0.0 & 0.4 & 0.1 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
                             7 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.5}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

As noted in the comments the space adjustments used here don't automatically adjust to changes in baseline stretch. The following modification addresses that, the two additional `omit` in the rows adding the over-braces, stop LaTeX spacing these lines to the baseline spacing, and as that is then a little too tight, a small vertical kern is added (in place of the negative kern in the version above)

```
\kbordermatrix{
\omit  &\multispan3\hfill$\scriptstyle S_1$\hfill&
   \multispan2\hfill$\scriptstyle S_2$\hfill&
  & \\
  \noalign{\kern-\kbrowsep\kern1ex}
\omit  &\multispan3\quad\downbracefill\quad&
   \multispan2 \quad\downbracefill\quad&  & \\
\hmmA
```

Comment: Thanks! Can a clip be set a little lower?

Comment: yes sure: the space between the brace and the column label is governed by the `20pt` and the space between the brace and the `S_1` label is governed by the `\kern-.2ex` fiddle with those numbers to suit your requirements.

Comment: Can you add a little explanation how this works?

Comment: This doesn't look good with my `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}`

Comment: I tried adding that and it made no difference as far as I can see? (Although I see you've accepted the tikz answer now, but I'm interested as to what went wrong here?)

Comment: Your solution worked and is ok. With `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}` I experienced that space between clip and label is too big. I already use `tikz` and `tikzmark` to highlight submatrices so Frédéric's answer is better for me. I didn't include submatrices highlighting in this question to keep example minimal.

Comment: ah sorry I added the package but didn't add the stretch, will add a note in the answer with a code update. (It's perfectly OK for you to accept the other answer though:-)

Comment: It is hard task to choose one answer out of two great ones ;)

Answer (score 2):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of [`nicematrix`](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\bar{P}=
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col,first-row]
\mathrm{state} &   1 &   2 &   4 &   3 &   6 &   5 &   7 \\
             1 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.6 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
             2 & 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.7 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
             4 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
             3 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
             6 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.7 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
             5 & 0.0 & 0.4 & 0.1 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
             7 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.5
\CodeAfter
  \OverBrace[shorten,yshift=1mm]{0-1}{0-3}{S_1}
  \OverBrace[shorten,yshift=1mm]{0-4}{0-5}{S_2}
\end{bNiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]