# Latex matrix tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I would like to created a matrix as the one in the picture. I read on another post that it is possible to do with tikz. My problem is that I want also to write on the left A= the matrix, with A= centered. is it possible to do using tikz? beause if I try just to write A=, I find A= aligned with the bottom of the matrix. [image]

Comment: Please post the code you used to create the picture in your question, but strip it down to the essentials before posting (i.e. remove all other text, remove all unnecessary packages, etc).

Comment: Have a look on [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15825/4821).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with `pstricks-add`. The idea is to set empty nodes at relevant places   in the matrix and connect them with the `\psbraces` command.

You can compile either with `xelatex`, or with `pdflatex`, if you use the `--enable-write18`switch (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX).

```
\documentclass[border =10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

\( \begin{postscript}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & \pnode[0,1.6ex]{R1}b & c &{d}\pnode[0,1.6ex]{R2} & x & \pnode[0,1.6ex]{Z1}x & x\pnode[0,1.6ex]{Z2}\pnode[1.25ex,1.5ex]{T2} \\ 
\pnode[-1.5ex, 1ex]{A1} e & f & g & h & x & x & x \\
y & y & y & y & y & y & y \\
\pnode[-1.5ex, -0.8ex]{A2}y & y & y & y & y & y & y \pnode[1.25ex, -1ex]{T1}\\
\pnode[-1.5ex, 1ex]{B1}y & y & y & y & y & y & y \pnode[1.25ex, 1.5ex]{U2}\\
i & j & k & l & x & x & x \\
\pnode[-1.1ex, -0.4ex]{B2}m &\pnode[0,-0.5ex]{S1}n & o\pnode[0,-0.5ex]{S2} &\pnode[0,-0.5ex]{W1} p & x & x\pnode[0,-0.5ex]{W2} & x \pnode[1.25ex, -0.5ex]{U1}
\end{bmatrix}
\psset{braceWidth=0.8pt, braceWidthInner=2pt, braceWidthOuter=2pt, nodesep=8pt, linejoin=1}
\psset{nodesepB=-4pt, nodesepA=0pt,  rot=-90}
\psbrace*[ref=cb](R2)(R1){$ R $}\psbrace*[ref=cb](Z2)(Z1){Z}
\psset{nodesepB=4pt, rot=90}
\psbrace*[ref=ct](S1)(S2){S}\psbrace*[ref=ct](W1)(W2){W}
\psset{nodesepB=0pt, nodesepA=4pt, rot=0}
\psbrace*[ref =cl](T1)(T2){T}\psbrace*[ref =cl](U1)(U2){U}
\psset{nodesepA=-4pt, rot=180}
\psbrace*[ref=cr](A1)(A2){A}\psbrace*[ref=cr](B1)(B2){B}
\end{postscript} \)

\end{document}
```

[image]