# Build a matrix with overbrace on some columns

Tags: math-mode, matrices, overbrace

I need to create a matrix and some overbraces on some entries at the top of the matrix like the following image(the entries are omitted)

[image]

I tried this code

```
$$  
A_n = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1&b_{1,2}&\overbrace{0, \cdots, 0}^{N_1-1}&b_{1,S_1+1}&\overbrace{0, \cdots, 0}^{N_2-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
```

and this was the result. I don't want the overbrace to be inside the matrix

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: In mathmode the symbol `$$...$$` is depreciated. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: You can see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15825/how-to-specify-two-level-row-and-column-labels-of-a-matrix-by-braces or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40/how-do-i-label-different-rows-or-columns-of-a-matrix-using-braces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this will help you (adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108009/add-overbrace-to-describe-a-column-of-matrix)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\bovermat[2]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\overbrace{\phantom{%
                    \begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}^{\text{#1}}}$}#2}
\newcommand\partialphantom{\vphantom{\frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{1,1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
    A_n
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1&b_{1,2}&\bovermat{1}{0,\cdots,0} & b_{1,s_{1}+1} &
    \bovermat{2}{0,\cdots,0}\\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{matrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]