# overbrace on columns of a matrix not working when the width of entries are different

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices, overbrace

I need to add overbrace on columns of a matrix. I tried [How do I label different rows or columns of a matrix using braces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40/how-do-i-label-different-rows-or-columns-of-a-matrix-using-braces) and [Build a matrix with overbrace on some columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446237/build-a-matrix-with-overbrace-on-some-columns) , They both work until no subscript or entry with different length is added to entries, after adding subscript it is not working properly. The following images shows the problem

This is the code

```
\[ \vphantom{% phantom stuff for correct box dimensions
    \begin{matrix}
    \overbrace{XYZ}^{\mbox{$R$}}\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
    \underbrace{pqr}_{\mbox{$S$}}
    \end{matrix}}%
\begin{matrix}% matrix for left braces
\vphantom{a}\\
\coolleftbrace{A}{e \\ y\\ y}\\
\coolleftbrace{B}{y \\i \\ m}
\end{matrix}%
\begin{bmatrix}
a & \coolover{R}{b & c & d & \cdots & y & h}\\
e & a & g & h & x & x & x \\
y & y & a & y & y & y & y \\
y & y & y & y & y & y & y \\
y & y & y & y & y & y & y \\
i & j & k & l & x & x & x \\
m &  \coolunder{S}{n & o}  & \coolunder{W}{p & x & x} & x
\end{bmatrix}%
\begin{matrix}% matrix for right braces
\coolrightbrace{x \\ x \\ y\\ y}{T}\\
\coolrightbrace{y \\ y \\ x }{U}
\end{matrix}\]
```

[image]

and after subscript the overbrace `R` is not on `h` anymore

[image]

This is the code

```
\[ \vphantom{% phantom stuff for correct box dimensions
    \begin{matrix}
    \overbrace{XYZ}^{\mbox{$R$}}\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
    \underbrace{pqr}_{\mbox{$S$}}
    \end{matrix}}%
\begin{matrix}% matrix for left braces
\vphantom{a}\\
\coolleftbrace{A}{e \\ y\\ y}\\
\coolleftbrace{B}{y \\i \\ m}
\end{matrix}%
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & \coolover{R}{b_{1,2} & b_{2,s_1+1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & h}\\
b_{1,2} & a_2 & b_{2,s_2+1} & h & x & x & x \\
b_{2,s_2+4} & b_{2,s_2+1} & a_3 & y & y & y & y \\
y & y & y & a_{s_{r+1}} & y & y & y \\
y & y & y & y & y & y & y \\
i & j & k & l & x & x & x \\
m &  \coolunder{S}{n & o}  & \coolunder{W}{p & x & x} & x
\end{bmatrix}%
\begin{matrix}% matrix for right braces
\coolrightbrace{x \\ x \\ y\\ y}{T}\\
\coolrightbrace{y \\ y \\ x }{U}
\end{matrix}\]
```

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete document with necessary preamble, beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some manual manipulation of the matrix content to place the braces. [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) is used to place boxes of equal size under the same `\eqmathbox[<tag>]` - this helps for the horizontal placement/spacing. Vertical alignment is done by placing an `array` before and after the `bmatrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox,xparse,lipsum}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\[
  \begin{array}{@{} r @{}}
    \mathstrut \\ % For \overbrace{..}^{R}
    \mathstrut \\
    {\scriptstyle A}\left\{\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
      \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
    \end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace \\
    {\scriptstyle B}\left\{\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
      \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
    \end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace \\
    \mathstrut % For \underbrace{..}_{S} and \underbrace{..}_{W}
  \end{array}
  \mkern-5mu
  \begin{bmatrix}% matrix for left braces
    a_1 & \multicolumn{6}{@{} c }{
      \smash{
        \overbrace{
          \begin{array}{ *{5}{c} c @{} }
            \eqmathbox[tb1]{b_{1,2}} &
              \eqmathbox[tb2]{b_{2,s_1+1}} &
              \eqmathbox[tb3]{0} &
              \eqmathbox[tb4]{\cdots} &
              \eqmathbox[tb5]{0} &
              \eqmathbox[tb6]{h}
          \end{array}
        }^{R}
      }
    } \\
    b_{1,2} & a_2 & \eqmathbox[tb2]{b_{2,s_2+1}} & h & \eqmathbox[tb4]{x} & \eqmathbox[tb5]{x} & \eqmathbox[tb6]{x} \\
    b_{2,s_2+4} & \eqmathbox[tb1]{b_{2,s_2+1}} & a_3 & y & y & y & y \\
    y & y & y & \eqmathbox[tb3]{a_{s_{r+1}}} & y & y & y \\
    y & y & y & y & y & y & y \\
    i & j & k & l & x & x & x \\
    m & \multicolumn{2}{@{} c @{}}{
      \smash{
        \underbrace{
          \begin{array}{c c}
            \eqmathbox[tb1]{n} & 
              \eqmathbox[tb2]{o}
          \end{array}
        }_{S}
      }
    } & \multicolumn{3}{@{} c @{}}{
      \smash{
        \underbrace{
          \begin{array}{c c c}
            \eqmathbox[tb3]{p} & 
              \eqmathbox[tb4]{x} & 
              \eqmathbox[tb5]{x}
          \end{array}
        }_{W}
      }
    } & x
  \end{bmatrix}
  \mkern-5mu
  \begin{array}{@{} l @{}}
    \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
      \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
    \end{array}\right\}{\scriptstyle T} \\
    \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
      \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
    \end{array}\right\}{\scriptstyle U}
  \end{array}
\]
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is perfect. thanks. How can I extend this to more than 6 columns inside the brace?

Comment: @Drupalist: I use `\multicolumn{6}` to make a cell that spans 6 columns. Inside that cell, I use an `array` with 6 columns (`*{5}{c} c`) and place every item inside an `\eqmathbox[<tag>]` with a unique `<tag>`. The idea is to capture the widest item in the entire matrix on a per-column basis for the span of the `array`. That way the column spacing will match within the `bmatrix` and the individual cell `array`s. Some fiddling with column separation (the `@{}`) was necessary, since `bmatrix` removes that from the left-/right-most columns.