# Text above matrices

Tags: amsmath, matrices, arrays

I am new to latex and I am trying to create this:

[image: this]

So far I have been able to create the matrices, like so:

```
\[
  N\textrm{ spectra}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1M} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2M} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{N1} & a_{N2} & \cdots & a_{NM}
  \end{bmatrix}\\
 \quad
  \begin{bmatrix}
    e_1 \\
    e_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    e_N
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
```

Does anyone know how can I add text above the matrices?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this with `stackrel` and `mbox`'s

```
\[
  N\textrm{ spectra}
  \stackrel{\mbox{$M$ components}}{%
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1M} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2M} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{N1} & a_{N2} & \cdots & a_{NM}
    \end{bmatrix}%
  }\ \quad
  \stackrel{\stackrel{\mbox{error}}{\mbox{detection}}}{%
    \begin{bmatrix}
    e_1 \\
    e_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    e_N
    \end{bmatrix}%
   }
\]
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way is to use `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
& & \text{error} \\
& \text{$M$ components} & \text{detection} \\
\text{$N$ spectra} &
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1M} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2M} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{N1} & a_{N2} & \cdots & a_{NM}
\end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}
    e_1 \\
    e_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    e_N
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

text where above the matrix? If you want a kind of heading above each column, then probably `\bordermatrix` is your friend, a plain TeX command but usable in LaTeX.

If you want a single item over the whole matrix, then any latex stacking construct would do the job, stackrel or a second single column array environment with your bmatrix on the second row or....

update: sorry I see you want this second form, didn't notice the image link originally.

so....

```
\[
  N\textrm{ spectra}
  \begin{smallmatrix} M\textrm{ components}\\\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1M} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2M} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{N1} & a_{N2} & \cdots & a_{NM}
  \end{bmatrix}\end{smallmatrix}\ \quad
  \begin{smallmatrix}
    \textrm{error}\\
    \textrm{detection}\\
   \begin{bmatrix}
    e_1 \\
    e_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    e_N
  \end{bmatrix}\end{smallmatrix}
\]
```

Answer (score 1):

For future interest, if your labeling needs become more complicated, there is the [`qbordermatrix`](https://github.com/righthandabacus/qbordermatrix) package which is somewhat more flexible than `\bordermatrix` as you can label rows or columns and put the labels on any of the four sides of the matrix. I have used this a bit, but have just noticed that the delimiters seem to extend somewhat higher above the top row of matrix elements than I would like.

Some of the questions on the TikZ package have also been helpful for my early attempts at more complicated labeling of matrices. For example, see [the responses on using braces to label some number of rows or columns of a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40/how-do-i-label-different-rows-or-columns-of-a-matrix-using-braces) .

There is also the [kbordermatrix](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/LaTeX.shtml) package which seems initially designed to label the along the top and down the left side of a matrix. The documentation says 
"I also have an experimental version that will put the labels on the right and bottom. If you ask, I will make it available." 
This package does seem to do a better job than qbordermatrix of making the top of the delimiters an appropriate height above the top row of matrix elements.

For a more flexible solution I think I'm going to have to play with tikz more now that I know how to  [use tikz in amsmath environments like align and gather](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59658/use-of-tikzpicture-matrix-in-align-or-gather-environment/59795#59795) .

Comment: Do you mind adding `kbordermatrix` to your answer for the sake of completeness? It can be found [on this page](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/LaTeX.shtml). And the documentation is [on this link](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.pdf)

Comment: @percusse You make a very good point. I had neglected this one some time ago as it didn't immediately seem designed to put labels below the bottom of a matrix, but the kbordermatrix package does have some advantage over the qbordermatrix for better delimiter sizing.