# use of tikzpicture matrix in align or gather environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, matrices

So far I have found using the matrix command in the TikZ package is the only way of drawing a T-shape around the bottom row and middle column of entries in a matrix. I now need to use this matrix in an align environment so that it can be used as part of a multi-line derivation - the equation environment is not appropriate.

I haven't found a similar question on this anywhere. Is it possible or advisable to do what I wish to do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is possible to do it: the only thing to remember is that the `tikzpicture` should be vertically aligned with the rest of the formula. To achieve this result you can use the option `[baseline=-0.5ex]`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
P&=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,
 left delimiter=(,
 right delimiter=),
 inner sep=2.5pt, 
 column 2/.style={green!50!black},
 ampersand replacement=\&] % <= to change col separator for align env
{
 x_1 \&  y_1  \\    
 x_2 \&  y_2  \\    
 x_3 \&  y_3  \\    
 x_4 \&  y_4  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
 z_1 &  w_1   \\
 z_2 &  w_2   \\
 z_3 &   w_3  \\
 z_4 &   w_4  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

that gives you:

[image]

> **EDIT**

Thanks to egreg's comment, I edit the answer to show with a picture the differences between the settings:

- `baseline=-0.5ex`
- `baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax`

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5]
%\let\&=\pgfmatrixnextcell % <= one choice to change col separator
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,
  left delimiter=(,
  right delimiter=),
  inner sep=2.5pt, 
  column 2/.style={green!50!black},
  ampersand replacement=\&] % <= to change col separator for align env
{
 x_1 \&  y_1   \\
 x_2 \&  y_2   \\
 x_3 \&  y_3   \\
 x_4 \&  y_4   \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
% new setting by egreg
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,
  left delimiter=(,
  right delimiter=),
  inner sep=2.5pt, 
  column 2/.style={green!50!black},
  ampersand replacement=\&] % <= to change col separator for align env
{
 x_1 \&  y_1   \\
 x_2 \&  y_2   \\
 x_3 \&  y_3   \\
 x_4 \&  y_4   \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
 +$\begin{pmatrix}
 z_1 &  w_1   \\
 z_2 &  w_2   \\
 z_3 &  w_3   \\
 z_4 &  w_4   \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

In the following picture the first matrix still have the option `baseline=-0.5` and it is a bit lower the other two matrices.

[image]

Comment: The "correct" setting seems to be `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]` (the change is small, but visible).

Comment: It's right (even if the change isn't so small, IMHO). I got the basic idea [in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57019/inline-tikz-vertical-centering#57020), but this setting is preferable. I'll edit the answer to show the differences between the two settings.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino The answer that you linked to works for inline text+inline TikZ picture. To be able to mimic the matrix alignment, it's better to put the matrix in the math environment and fine tune all the spacings, precisely copying the `amsmath` specs. As you can see, the parentheses match but the entries are off. Hence, there is still a need for further tuning ;) In this environment the best is to start with a node name and use `baseline=(m.center)` then one needs to tighten the delimiter spacing and nodes need to be anchored by their bases etc. I did quite a lot adjustments :)

Comment: Also note, that within the TikZ picture there must be no empty lines, when it is contained in an `align` environment

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Claudio is the simplest in the case given. It's also possible to use

If the matrix is : (`\int` only to show something that imbalance the matrix)

```
{
 x_1 \&  y_1   \\
 x_2 \&  y_2   \\
 \int \&   y_3   \\
}
```

You can use

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=(m.west)]    %     (m-2-1.base)     [baseline=-0.5ex]
%\let\&=\pgfmatrixnextcell % <= one choice to change col separator
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),inner sep=2.5pt, column 2/.style={green!50!black},
 ampersand replacement=\&,draw] (m)% <= to change col separator for align env
```

or

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=(m-2-1.base)]    %         [baseline=-0.5ex]
%\let\&=\pgfmatrixnextcell % <= one choice to change col separator
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),inner sep=2.5pt, column 2/.style={green!50!black},
 ampersand replacement=\&,draw] (m)
```

Interesting is you want to align with another text in your matrix.

The result with my examples is not the same as that obtained with `baseline=-0.5ex`. It depends what you want to get.

Remark : in some case, `baseline=(current bounding box.west)` for example is useful.

Comment: Thanks to all contributors, I have a working solution now. For people new to tikz like me, I wasn't aware of the importance of "ampersand replacement" in the \matrix when in the align environment. I will post an (almost) MWE to show the flavour of what I intend to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

For those wondering what I was trying to do, here's an (almost) MWE to give the flavour of what I managed with the helpful posts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

Now using `$m=n$`

\begin{align*}
\gamma_n^{-1} &= \mu_{2n} \gamma_{n,0} + \mu_{2n-1} \gamma_{n,1} + \cdots + \mu_{n} \gamma_{n,n} \\
            & = \sum_{j=0}^{n} (-)^j \mu_{2n-j} \frac{\gamma_n} {\Delta_n} 
\det \begin{pmatrix}              
 \mu_0 &  \cdots & \mu_{n-j-1}  & , &   \mu_{n-j +1} &  \cdots  & \mu_{n} \\
                  \vdots & \ddots &  \vdots & &  \vdots  &\ddots & \vdots  \\
                  \mu_{n-1} &  \cdots & \mu_{2n-j-2} & , &   \mu_{2n-j}  &  \cdots &  \mu_{2n-1} 
                 \end{pmatrix} \\
  & = \vdots \quad \mbox{(lines skipped!)} \\
  &=  \frac{\gamma_n} {\Delta_n}
\det 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
 \tikzset{BarreStyle/.style =   {opacity=.6,line width=0.5 mm,line cap=round,color=#1}}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter = (,right delimiter = ),row sep=10pt,column sep = 10pt, ampersand replacement=\&] (m) {
\mu_0 \& \cdots \&  \mu_{n-j-1}  \& \mu_{n-j} \&   \mu_{n-j +1} \&  \cdots  \& \mu_{n} \\
                  \vdots \& \ddots \& \vdots \& \vdots \&  \vdots \& \ddots \& \vdots  \\
                  \mu_{n-1} \& \cdots \& \mu_{2n-j-2} \& \mu_{2n-j-1} \&  \mu_{2n-j}  \& \cdots \& \mu_{2n-1}  \\
                  \mu_{n} \& \cdots \& \mu_{2n-j-1} \& \mu_{2n-j} \&  \mu_{2n-j+1}  \& \cdots \&  \mu_{2n} \\
};
 \draw[BarreStyle=green] (m-1-4.north east) -- (m-4-4.north east) -- (m-4-7.north east)-- (m-4-7.south east)--(m-4-1.south west)--(m-4-1.north west)  --(m-4-4.north west) --(m-1-4.north west) -- (m-1-4.north east) ;
\end{tikzpicture} \\
&= \gamma_n \frac{ \Delta_{n+1} } { \Delta_n }. 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could improve the outline of the green shape with the