# How to highlight a single element in a matrix?

Tags: matrices, highlighting

I am trying to write out the LU decomposition of a matrix A. I am able to highlight the pivot column with elements below the pivot element except when I get to the last column. Does anyone know how I can highlight the last element, 2, in the same format? Or do you have suggestions of other ways that I could do this?

Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{%
 highlight/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=blue!30,draw,
 fill opacity=0.2,thick,inner sep=0pt}
 }
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,
 baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {#2};}
 %
\newcommand{\Highlight}[1][submatrix]{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
\node[highlight,fit=(left.north west) (right.south east)] (#1) {};}
}



\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
\hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
A =
\left[ 
\begin{array} {*4{c}}
 \tikzmark{left}{2}& 1 & -1 & 4 \\ 
-4 & -3 & 6 & -3 \\ 
2 & -3 & 20 & 23 \\
 \tikzmark{right}{4} & 2 & 13 & 7
\end{array}
\right] 
\Highlight[first]
\sim 
\begin{matrix} 
\\ 
\mbox{$R_2+2R_1$} \\ 
\mbox{$R_3-R_1$} \\
\mbox{$R_4-2R_2$}
\end{matrix}
&\left[ 
2 & 1 & -1 & 4 \\ 
0 & \tikzmark{left}{-1} & 4 & 5 \\ 
0 & -4 & 21 & 19 \\
0 & \tikzmark{right}{0} & 15 & -1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\Highlight[first] \\
\sim
\begin{matrix} 
\\ 
\\ 
\mbox{$R_3-4R_2$} \\
\mbox{ }
\end{matrix}
&\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
2 & 1 & -1 & 4 \\ 
0 & -1 & 4 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & \tikzmark{left}{5} & -1 \\
0 & 0 & \tikzmark{right}{15} & -1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\Highlight[first]\\
\sim
\begin{matrix} 
\\ 
\\ 
\\
\mbox{$R_4-3R_3$}
\end{matrix}
&\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
2 & 1 & -1 & 4 \\ 
0 & -1 & 4 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{matrix}
\right]
=U
\end{align*}



\end{document}
```

I need the last element, 2, to be highlighted just like the other pivot columns.

I am new user so I am not allowed to post an image but I hope someone can help with this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Thanks for posting a complete document, but you need to: 1. Eliminate unnecessary packages, and 2. Make it compilable, so that those trying to help can have something to start from.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have made the suggested changes. Hopefully, it is easier now.

Comment: Still does not compile for me: `LaTeX Error: \begin{align*} on input line 34 ended by \end{matrix}`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**update**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\begin{document}​  
\newcommand\hlight[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture,baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]\node[rectangle,fill=blue!50,rounded corners,fill opacity = 0.2,draw,thick,text opacity =1] {$#1$};} 

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
           c &  -a    &   0    & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  &  0 \\
          -b &   \hlight{a}   &  -a    & \ddots &        &        & \vdots \\
           0 &  -b    &   c    & \ddots & \ddots &        & \vdots \\
      \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
      \vdots &        & \ddots & \ddots &   c    &  -a    &  0 \\
      \vdots &        &        & \ddots &  -b    &   c    & -a \\
           0 & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  &   0    &  -b    &  c
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}  
\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: That's nice! Is there a way I can get the rounded edges just like adjust the opacity like the other columns highlighted?

Comment: yres add rounded corners in the node. Be careful I made a mistake in the macro : c instead of #1

Comment: \newcommand\hlight[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture,baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]\node[rectangle,fill=blue!30,rounded corners,fill opacity = 0.2,draw,thick] {#1};}

Comment: That's my new command but 2 isn't really visible, i.e. it looks faded compared to the other elements. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes your problem here is that you mix `blue!30` very light blue and `opacity=.2` very light opacity then you can add `text opacity=1`. I updated my answer and don't forget `$#1$`

Answer (score 8):

Here is a [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)-free version using [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) that should get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

%\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{%
  \ooalign{\hss\makebox[0pt]{\fcolorbox{green!30}{red!40}{$#1$}}\hss\cr\phantom{$#1$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
  A = \left[\begin{array} {*4{c}}
    \highlight{2} &  1 & -1 &  4 \\ 
   -4 & -3 &  6 & -3 \\ 
    2 & \highlight{-3} & 20 & 23 \\
    4 &  2 & \highlight{13} &  7
  \end{array}\right] 
\]

\end{document}​
```

For a quick course in `\ooalign`, see [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764). Of course, other improvements like colour selection (through optional arguments, say) are all possible.

Comment: yes your answer  is a tikz-free version but you change the form of the matrix. Tikz version is form-free but I'm sure that you can do the same only with TeX :)

Comment: @Altermundus: The box is set in a zero-width box which shouldn't change the horizontal shape of the matrix. Any vertical adjustment could be overcome by `\smash`, if needed. In the example presented by the OP, this didn't seem to be problematic, so I left it out.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution based on TikZ just for matrices.

Basically, using the property of TikZ `matrices`, it is possible to select a single element and it will be highlighted in by means of the `background` library. With this approach you don't have to place markers inside the matrices, but you have to put the code to highlight elements inside the `pgfonlayer` environment. Notice that the matrix it's vertically aligned inside the math environment thanks to `[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]` (see [use of tikzpicture matrix in align or gather environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59658/use-of-tikzpicture-matrix-in-align-or-gather-environment/59660#59660)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{myback}
\pgfsetlayers{myback,background,main}

\tikzset{mycolor/.style = {rounded corners,line width=1bp,color=#1}}%
\tikzset{myfillcolor/.style = {rounded corners,draw,fill=#1}}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\highlight}{O{blue!40} m m}{%
\draw[mycolor=#1] (#2.north west)rectangle (#3.south east);
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fhighlight}{O{blue!40} m m}{%
\draw[myfillcolor=#1] (#2.north west)rectangle (#3.south east);
}    

\begin{document}

\[P=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
\matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
{
2 & 1 & -1 & 4 \\ 
0 & -1 & 4 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 15 & -1\\
};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{myback}
\highlight{m-2-2}{m-2-2}
\fhighlight{m-3-3}{m-3-3}
\fhighlight[orange]{m-4-4}{m-4-4}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

The same result could be achieved by means of the `fit` library using, again, a background layer.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,backgrounds,fit}
\pgfdeclarelayer{myback}
\pgfsetlayers{myback,background,main}

\begin{document}

\[P=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
\matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
{
2 & 1 & -1 & 4 \\ 
0 & -1 & 4 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 15 & -1\\
};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{myback}
\node[fit=(m-2-2),rounded corners,draw=blue,scale=0.6]{};
\node[fit=(m-3-3),rounded corners,draw,fill=blue!40,scale=0.6]{};
\node[fit=(m-4-4),rounded corners,draw,fill=orange,scale=0.6]{};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{nicematrix}

 \begin{document}

 \newcommand\focus[2]{\Block[draw,fill=#1,rounded-corners]{}{#2}}

 $\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin]
 p & q & r \\
 \focus{red!15}{p} & q & r \\
 p & \focus{blue!15}{q} & r \\
 \end{pNiceMatrix}$

 \end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]