# Create xkcd style diagram in TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, fun

The unique style of the diagrams at [xkcd](http://xkcd.org) has an informative but nice hand-drawn touch. I guess they are actually drawn by hand but just recently on our partner site for Mathematica someone asked how to draw a similar diagram such as this one with Mathematica's plot functions ([xkcd-style-graphs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs)).

[image: xkcd diagram]

Now without Mathematica this should be possible as well but I have a hard time getting the details right. Can such a diagram be created in TeX with a similar design? My first attempt does not look particularly great but here it is (the font is from http://antiyawn.com/uploads/humorsans.html):

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz,color}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Humor-Sans}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={line width=1pt}}

    \begin{axis}[%
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        xtick={1.2, 2.9, 4.5},
        xticklabels={-3 days, -1 day, 5 minutes},
        yticklabels={}
    ]
    % 1st plot
    \addplot [cyan!80!white, samples=200, domain=0:6] {0.05*rnd+3+(sin(deg(x))^2)/sqrt(x)*exp(-(x-2))};
    % white background for 2nd plot
    \addplot [white, samples=200, domain=0:6,line width=4pt] {0.05*rnd+0.4*x+2+x^2*sin(deg(x))^2*exp(-x)}; 
    % 2nd plot
    \addplot [red!80!white, samples=200, domain=0:6] {0.05*rnd+0.4*x+2+x^2*sin(deg(x))^2*exp(-x)}; 
    \end{axis} 

    \node at (2.7,4.6) {downhill};
    \draw  plot[smooth, tension=.7,line width=2pt] coordinates {(1.2679,5.5206) (1.9454,5.493) (2.4017,4.9261)};

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image: first attempt]

Comment: The reason why your plots seem to have too much noise in them is that you use the same number of samples for the random part. You could try creating a table with "clean" function values using `pgfplotstable`, then add random steps with a lower number of samples and plot the result.

Comment: There is a variation of this using R to generate the graphic. With the intermediate use of knitr or sweave this can be integrated with LaTeX to import a very nice version of XKCD like graphics. See http://drunks-and-lampposts.com/2012/10/02/clegg-vs-pleb-an-xkcd-esque-chart/ I am going to use this technique to draw graphics for my statistics class to 'emulate' my handwriting. It will get a laugh.

Comment: Congratulations on the Great Question badge :)

Comment: I know I'm really late to the party, but xkcd is hand drawn. [Source](http://xkcd.com/1015/) (check the title text).

Comment: [This is also possible using matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/screenshots.html#xkcd-style-sketch-plots).

Comment: related: stackoverflow.com/questions/12675147/how-can-we-make-xkcd-style-graphs-in-r

Answer (score 327, accepted):

This has been a topic for a few questions on this site and you can find many examples of such human-like typesetting, the most famous being the great

[How do I make my document look like it was written by a Cthulhu-worshipping madman?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm)

and also slightly related ones

[Simulating hand-drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines)

[TikZ two-blocks matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69990/tikz-two-blocks-matrix)

that I can remember (because I've posted some answers) but please add more if I'm missing the obvious ones.

Regarding the answer, you can use decorations instead of random perturbations to your plots such that they are handled by TikZ instead. Also you can use a double line to achieve that white overlay over the previous line.

<strike>I don't have the Humor Sans font but I've used another similar font for using PDFLaTeX directly.</strike> Guys at SO have a better replacement for the font: [xkcd style graphs in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675147/xkcd-style-graphs-in-r)

(The updated example needs XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX!!)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{xkcd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={random steps,segment length=1mm,amplitude=0.2pt}]
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={line width=1pt}}

\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
xtick={1.2, 2.9, 4.5},
xticklabels={-3 days, -1 day, 5 minutes},
yticklabels={},
every inner x axis line/.append style={-},
every inner y axis line/.append style={-},
decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=0.3pt},decorate,
every tick/.style={thick,black,decorate}
]
\begin{scope}[decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.5pt},decorate]
\addplot [cyan!80!white, samples=30, domain=0:6] {3+(sin(deg(x))^2)/sqrt(x)*exp(-(x-2))};
\addplot [white,double=red!80!white, samples=30, domain=0:6,double distance=1.0pt] {0.4*x+2+x^2*sin(deg(x))^2*exp(-x)}; 
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\draw (1.2679,5.5206) to[bend left] (2.7,4.6) node[below] {downhill};
\begin{scope}[shift={(7cm,3cm)},thick]
\draw[line join=round,decorate] (0.6cm,-0.1cm) arc (45:275:0.4cm) arc (275:410:0.38cm);
\draw[decorate] (0.4cm,-0.9cm)coordinate (n) -- ++(0.1,-1cm) coordinate (a) -- +(-70:1.2cm) (a) --+(-110:1.2cm);
\draw[decorate] (n) -- ++(-5:0.4cm) --+(10:0.5cm);
\draw[decorate] (n) -- ++(-55:0.4cm) --+(2:0.5cm);
\node[align=left,scale=0.5] (c) at (0.5,2){I WON'T EVEN TRY \\TO BE FUNNY LIKE XKCD};
\draw[thin] (c) to[in=110,out=-90] ++(0,-0.5cm) node[below,align=left,scale=0.5] 
(d) {BUT THEN AGAIN, WHADDA\\ HELL! A NEUTRINO GOES \\TO A BAR...};
\draw[thin] (d) to[in=80,out=-90] ++(0,-1cm);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: ba dum tss...]

<strike>You can extend the effectiveness of the decoration to axes too if you remove the scope and supply the decoration options to the axis environment.</strike>

**EDIT**  : added some clarification for the axes and some bonus stuff

**EDIT2** : switched to a better font.

---

And finally I think it's not the wavy lines or the cartoonish display but the dry-humor of the author that makes them so funny so I don't think this would bring anything closer to those of **xkcd**.

Comment: Awesomeness has a name: percusse. `:)`

Comment: I've been holding the mouse over the plot for ages now and I have yet to see the punchline displayed.

Comment: the axes are still too straight IMO

Comment: @heinrich5991 as mentioned in the answer "You can extend the effectiveness of the decoration to axes too if you remove the scope and supply the decoration options to the axis environment."

Comment: I'm going to use this style in the thesis just to see my supervisor reaction...

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Added a student for you :)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I never thought this would catch so  much attention. The humor certainly can't be copied, but you gave it a nice geeky touch. :)

Comment: heading towards a well-deserved Great Answer badge- congrats percusse!

Comment: @cmhughes Still don't quite get what happened with this but thanks anyway. Next stop *Unsung Hero* which is next to impossible here :)

Comment: It is not working: ! Package fontspec Error: The font "xkcd" cannot be found.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The neutrino asks the bartender, "how much for a beer?"  The bartender replies, "for you, no charge."  Further research: https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/a_neutrino_walks_into_a_bar/

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes almost 7 year wait for the punchline, but thanks!

Comment: No problem, @DavidCarlisle I just needed the upgrade that provided `\expanded`.  Then the joke expansion worked for me.

Comment: Is  `\usetikzlibrary {decorations}` required in order to use `decoration`?

Answer (score 118):

If creating plots using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) (python) is an option, take a look at ["XKCDify "](http://jakevdp.github.com/blog/2012/10/07/xkcd-style-plots-in-matplotlib/) (sorry, this isn't a "TeX answer", but inclusion of matplotlib-generated plots in TeX documents is common enough I think it's worth mentioning this here).

[image]

Answer (score 26):

I needed something like this and got inspired by the previous answer. I tried to clean up the code and to make it easy to use, as a single `xkcd axis`.

The single option changes the all style:

[image: The sample plot with or without the option]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{emerald}


\pgfplotsset{
  xkcd/.style={
    decoration={
      name=random steps,
      segment length=2pt,
      amplitude=0.3pt,
    },
    line width=1pt,
    line join=round,
    line cap=round,
    decorate,
  },
}
\pgfplotsset{
  xkcd axis/.style={%
    axis on top,
    xkcd,
    every non boxed x axis/.style={
      xtick align=center,
      enlarge x limits=true,
      x axis line style={-Straight Barb[round]}
    },
    every non boxed y axis/.style={
      ytick align=center,
      enlarge y limits=true,
      y axis line style={-Straight Barb[round]}
    },
    every tick/.append style={
      black,
      xkcd,
    },
    every axis plot post/.append style={
      double= . ,
      mark=none,
      draw=white,
      double distance=1pt,
    },
    every axis legend/.append style={
      xkcd,
    },
    tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true},
    execute at begin axis={\ECFAugie},
  },
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    xkcd axis,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xtick={1.2, 2.9, 4.5},
    xticklabels={-3 days, -1 day, 5 minutes},
    xlabel=time,
    ylabel={what is this, exactly ?},
    ]
    \addplot +[samples=30, domain=1:6] {3+(sin(deg(x))^2)/sqrt(x)*exp(-(x-2))};
    \addlegendentry{Hello}
    \addplot +[samples=30, domain=1:6] {0.4*x+2+x^2*sin(deg(x))^2*exp(-x)}; 
    \addlegendentry{World}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    %xkcd axis,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xtick={1.2, 2.9, 4.5},
    xticklabels={-3 days, -1 day, 5 minutes},
    xlabel=time,
    ]
    \addplot +[samples=30, domain=1:6] {3+(sin(deg(x))^2)/sqrt(x)*exp(-(x-2))};
    \addlegendentry{Hello}
    \addplot +[samples=30, domain=1:6] {0.4*x+2+x^2*sin(deg(x))^2*exp(-x)}; 
    \addlegendentry{World}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\usepackage{emerald}` you could install the font on your system and then `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\newfontfamily\ECFAugie{augie}`. Works perfectly with `XeLaTeX`. Obviously you could name the new font family something more informative like `\myxkcdfont`.

Answer (score 21):

A bit late, but I've just played around a bit and created an xkcd-like TikZ decoration.  I probably added it to the wrong question.  It's [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445690/52582).  Example below.

[image: Example adapted from matplotlib]