# ! Argument of \pgfmathrnd@@ has an extra }

Tags: tikz-pgf, random-numbers

The followin code gives this error :

```
! Argument of \pgfmathrnd@@ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12    }

? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12    }

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on bob.log.

Done.
```

What is wrong ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{Rnd}
{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{.5cm}{.5cm}}
{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
{
    \pgfpathcircle{%
        %\pgfpoint{.25cm}{.25cm}}{.4pt}
        \pgfpoint{\pgfmathrnd*.25cm}{\pgfmathrnd*.25cm}}{.4pt}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[pattern=Rnd] (0,0) rectangle (5,5) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Section 97.2: `\pgfpoint{<x coord>}{<y coord}` Yields a point location. The coordinates are given as TeX dimensions.

Comment: I don't understand what it means. By the way, I have no 97.2 section in my pfg 3.00 manual. Witch is the page, please ?

Comment: You should use the function directly, see my answer in [Fill style that looks like hand-drawn / hand-filled with crayon](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78044/13304) for instance.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino An answer?

Comment: @egreg: It deserves one, indeed. I will answer later in the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it is not possible to use the macros `\pgfmathrnd`, `\pgfmathrand` or `\pgfmathrandom` otherwise the result is not in the appropriate form to be parsed. The correct way is to use directly the functions `rnd`, `rand` or `random`:

```
\pgfpoint{rnd*.25cm}{rnd*.25cm}}{.4pt}
```