# Sketch sinusoidal wave in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the easiest way to **sketch** a sinusoidal wave in PGF/Tikz? I have tried this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[loosely dotted] (0,0) grid (4,2);
  \draw[x=0.5cm,y=1cm, ultra thick, red]
    (0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0) sin (4,1) cos (5,0) sin (6,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I get the grid to cover all the wave? Is there a better way of **sketching** (not plotting) functions/waves?

Comment: If you want the grid to cover the curve, change the coordinates in the `grid` line to the corners of a rectangle that encloses the curve.  Can you explain more what you mean by "sketch" vs. "plot"?  Do you want something that looks hand drawn?

Comment: If you want more hand drawn, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/create-xkcd-style-diagram-in-tex

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: I can't get it to work, how would I change the coordinates in this instance? By sketch I mean that I don't get Tikz to plot it for me, I put in the points it should connect and with what shape.

Comment: try `\draw[loosely dotted] (0,-2) grid (4,2)` for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you can adjust the grid by choosing the coordinates on the line with `grid` in it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[loosely dotted] (0,-1) grid (3,1);
  \draw[x=0.5cm,y=1cm, ultra thick, red]
    (0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0) sin (4,1) cos (5,0) sin (6,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Your second `\draw` line changes the scale of the *x* axis to `0.5cm` instead of `1cm` as is the default.  So `(3,1)` on the first line is the same point as `(6,1)` on the second line.

[image: sample code output]

If you just want to interpolate points on a curve smoothly, you can use the `plot` command of tikz like so:

```
\draw[x=0.5cm,y=1cm, ultra thick, red]
    plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,1) (1,0) (2,-1) (3,0) (4,1) (5,0) (6,-1)};
```

There is a `tension` key that adjusts the curviness of the smoothing but frankly I couldn't get anything that looked better to me than the default.

[image: sample code output]

Another option would be to use Bézier curves.  However, in specifying a Bézier curve between two points, two *additional* points are needed.  These two describe the velocity vector coming out of and into each point.

```
\draw[x=0.5cm,y=1cm, ultra thick, red]  (0,1) 
  .. controls ([xshift=\dx]0,1)  and ([xshift=-\dx]2,-1)  .. (2,-1) 
  .. controls ([xshift=\dx]2,-1) and ([xshift=-\dx]4,1)   .. (4,1) 
  .. controls ([xshift=\dx]4,1)  and ([xshift=-\dx]6,-1)  .. (6,-1) ;
```

[image: sample code output]

You'll notice I took advantage of the symmetry to eliminate the coordinates along the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The `trembling` module of the `Asymptote` offers an object of class `tremble`
to be set up, to apply a trembling transform on an arbitrary curve. `sketch.asy`:

```
import graph; // for cos
import trembling;
import math; // for the grid

size(8cm);

real xmin=0, xmax=1.5pi;
real ymin=-1, ymax=1;

tremble tr=tremble(angle=20,frequency=0.6,random=50,fuzz=1);
path sinesketch=tr.deform(graph(cos,xmin,xmax)); 

int rows=2, cols=3;
add(
  shift(xmin,ymin)*scale((xmax-xmin)/cols,(ymax-ymin)/rows)
  *grid(cols,rows, red+dotted+1.2pt)
);
draw(sinesketch,darkblue+1.2pt);
```

Run `asy -f pdf sketch.asy` to get a standalone `sketch.pdf`.