# Work diagram help

Tags: diagrams, graphs

I am trying to create this sort of diagram (or graph). The X axis is time, Y axis are projects/tasks and lines through them are people (employees) working on certain task in given time period. I've found similar diagram, which is enclosed below. It is a star wars plot/story diagram from http://xkcd.com/657/. More or less sums up my needs. I know I could draw it by hand in eg. LibreOffice Draw or such a program, but first I'd like to know if there's any possibility of having this directly in tex.

BTW: if any of you know the exact name of this diagram/graph, please let me know.

Thank you all in advance

[image]

Comment: I added the image, as well as a link to the original (http://xkcd.com/657/) to your post. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Welcome- have you seen [Create xkcd style diagram in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74878)