# Random decoration of plot axis messes up direction of axis arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've been experimenting with "xkcdifying" a plot I want to make, based on the information found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74881/46356) and some pasting from other sources (this is my first time using pgfplots). Everything worked fine so far, until I wanted to give the axes arrows. But it seems that the `random steps` decoration always turns up the arrow head on the x axis:

[image]

If the marked line in the below code is commented out, the arrow is displayed correctly again, but of course the nice random effect is gone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={line width=1pt}}

\begin{axis}[%
  axis lines=middle,
  decoration={%
    random steps, % CRITICAL LINE
    segment length=1mm,
    amplitude=0.2pt
  }, 
  every tick/.style={thick,black,decorate},
  enlarge x limits=true,
  y tick style={draw=none},
  yticklabel=\empty,
  every inner x axis line/.append style={->},
  every inner y axis line/.append style={->},
]
\begin{scope}[decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.5pt},decorate]
\addplot [blue,samples=50, domain=0:120] {(2479*x^6)/5513508000000-(13697*x^5)/61261200000+(7935509*x^4)/220540320000-(1889983*x^3)/816816000+(2038007*x^2)/40840800+(335201*x)/1021020};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, am I right in my guess that this is an error due to the randomization? And how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is due to how axis lines are drawn and seems to me a candidate as a bug. Consider the following;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mydeco/.style={
  decoration={%
    random steps, % CRITICAL LINE
    segment length=1mm,
    amplitude=1pt,#1,
    post length=10mm,
    post= lineto % Change to " moveto "!
  },
  decorate,
}
]
\begin{axis}[%
  line width=1pt,
  axis lines*=middle,
  every inner x axis line/.style={->,mydeco},
  every inner y axis line/.style={->,mydeco},
]
\begin{scope}[mydeco={segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.5pt},decorate]
\addplot [blue,samples=50, domain=0:120,->] {(2479*x^6)/5513508000000-(13697*x^5)/61261200000+(7935509*x^4)/220540320000-(1889983*x^3)/816816000+(2038007*x^2)/40840800+(335201*x)/1021020};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}

\draw[mydeco,->,red,ultra thick] (0,0) -- (5,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I tried to stop the decoration 10mm before the path end. It is OK for paths but not for axis lines. This means there is a move operation somewhere that changes the *current path* such that post length and post path drawing mechanism is not applied to the axis line. As an example change `lineto` to `moveto` and we can replicate that behavior on other paths too.

I will attempt to have a look but that part of the code is really involved due to 3D/2D settings. Maybe Christian can help here. Otherwise we can open a ticket. Then randomized paths would have the arrow head automatically without any `post=...` tweak.

---

It turns out that this behaviour is due to a missing expansion in an internal PGFPlots macro. PGFPlots uses a decoration to place axis discontinuity marks, which requires setting `pre length` and `post length` values for the decoration. PGFPlots sets `pre length` and `post length` using macros (called `\xdisstart`, `\xdisend`, etc.). If no discontinuity is used, these macros are set to `0pt`. However, for some reason, arrow tips aren't placed correctly when the `pre length` and `post length` values contain unexpanded macros. So in order to fix the behaviour, you can redefine an internal PGFPlots macro by placing the following code in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplots@drawaxis@innerlines@onorientedsurf#1#2#3{%
    \if2\csname pgfplots@#1axislinesnum\endcsname
        \draw[/pgfplots/every inner #1 axis line,%
            decorate,%
            #1discont,%
            decoration={% Expand the macros before setting the values
                pre length/.expand twice=\csname #1disstart\endcsname,
                post length/.expand twice=\csname #1disend\endcsname
            }
            ]
        \pgfextra
        \csname pgfplotspointonorientedsurfaceabsetupforset#3\endcsname{\csname pgfplots@logical@ZERO@#3\endcsname}{2}%
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfplotspointonorientedsurfaceab{\csname pgfplots@#1min\endcsname}{\csname pgfplots@logical@ZERO@#2\endcsname}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfplotspointonorientedsurfaceab{\csname pgfplots@#1max\endcsname}{\csname pgfplots@logical@ZERO@#2\endcsname}}%
        \endpgfextra
        ;
    \fi
}%
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: The problem seems to originate from `\pgfplots@drawaxis@innerlines@onorientedsurf` in `pgfplots.code.tex`, which draws the axis lines when using `axis lines=middle`. In the `\draw` command, the `every inner #1 axis line` style is followed by a hard coded `decoration` for the axis discontinuity, which sets `post length=\csname #1disend\endcsname`. `\xdisend` happens to be `0pt` when no discontinuity is used, which causes the arrow head problem. The problem can be fixed somewhat heavy-handedly by setting `xdisend/.store in=\xdisend,xdisend=1bp` in the `every inner x axis line/.style`.

Comment: @Jake Cool! Thanks for the surgery. If you want I can delete this and you write an answer? However, it doesn't explain the arrow head mismatch since you can have correct arrowheads with the decoration on regular paths (just remove the `post` related stuff from the style). Hence, there is additional action after the axis lines are plotted. Maybe the if conditions are disrupting by installing empty paths. I can see some relevant stuff but I don't exactly understand what those conditions do.

Comment: Ah, what a thriller: It seems that the problem is due to the `\csname #1disend\endcsname` not being expanded. If  `pre length=\csname #1disstart\endcsname, post length=\csname #1disend\endcsname` is replaced with `pre length/.expand twice=\csname #1disstart\endcsname, post length/.expand twice=\csname #1disend\endcsname`, the arrow heads are placed correctly, even without specifying a `post length`. Don't ask me why that happens, though. Maybe this would be worth opening a bug report for.

Comment: I agree that there is something wrong with that code. I believe it should not activate / reconfigure decorations unless one really has discontinuities. I see that there is an expansion issue around it as well (something with '0pt' which should be '0pt '), although I cannot reproduce @Jake's last comment.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger We found more evidence in the chat. Starting around here you can see more :) http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13834867#13834867

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: I edited the answer with an explanation of one way of fixing this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for all your expert help! Given that now the author knows about this, should a bug still be filed? (I don't even think I can do that without a Souceforge account; or at least I didn't find the right place.)

Comment: Guys, thanks for your analysis! That's indeed good work. I'll take this as a bug report, no need to file a ticket on sourceforge.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Thank you for your wonderful support for bugs and quirks we come up with all the time :)