# Drawing Phase Diagrams Using MetaPost

Tags: metapost

I wanted to take the solution provided by @Thruston at [phases (stages) of economic cycle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210723/phases-stages-of-economic-cycle). However, when I copied and pasted the first block of code provided as a solution in English, I could not get the output in latex. I am getting the error `Missing \begin{document}` What could be the causes?

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit? Do you get an error? A different output? Maybe also, to make this question a bit more independent, you can provide the example code that you use.

Comment: I am getting an error, `Missing \begin{document}`.

Comment: I think that's a rather old one, so you probably need to run it through `mpost` not `lualatex` -- I'll have a look at the original Q.

Comment: i've revised [my old answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267516/15036) to make it clearer how to compile it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the original diagram was designed to be compiled with Metapost directly -- "the old way".  So to get the desired output, you should compile it with `mpost` rather than any LaTeX engine.  If you do that it will create a `.eps` file in Encapsulated PostScript which you can render into various forms with GhostScript, `epstopdf` etc.

Or you can adapt it for modern usage with `lualatex` and `luamplib`.  The adaptation is pretty easy.

Start with this template file.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
% drawing-commands-go-here
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Then copy everything in the source file between `beginfig` and `endfig` and put it in the template in place of the comment line.

Then you can compile it with `lualatex` to get a PDF output file directly.

Here is a worked example:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

string ff; ff = "phvr8r";

% fiddle with the parameters to get a nice rising wave
path wave;
wave = (origin for t=1 step 1 until 3*360 + 24: 
                  -- (2/3t,70 sind(t)) shifted (0,1/3*t) 
               endfor) scaled 3/4 shifted (21,34);

% draw the straight arrow and the wave on top
drawarrow point 0 of wave -- point 3*360 of wave scaled 1.05 
          dashed evenly withcolor .5[blue, white];
draw wave withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor .67 green;

% labels
picture s[];                % center each label and push it up/down slightly
s1 = "peak"      infont ff; s1 := s1 shifted (-1/2 xpart urcorner s1, 6);
s2 = "trough"    infont ff; s2 := s2 shifted (-1/2 xpart urcorner s2, -12);
s3 = "expansion" infont ff; s3 := s3 shifted (-1/2 xpart urcorner s3, 6);
s4 = "recession" infont ff; s4 := s4 shifted (-1/2 xpart urcorner s4, 6);

% add the labels in the "right" places 
t = 0; n = 0;
forever:
  dt := directiontime right of subpath(t,infinity) of wave;
  exitif dt < 0;
  t := t + dt;
  n := n + 1;
  if odd(n): draw s1 shifted point t of wave withcolor .67 blue;  
     if n>1: draw s3 rotated angle direction t-dt/2 of wave
                             shifted point t-dt/2 of wave ; fi
  else:      draw s2 shifted point t of wave withcolor .67 red;  
             draw s4 rotated angle direction t-dt/2 of wave
                     shifted point t-dt/2 of wave;
  fi
endfor

% do the axes and titles
path xx, yy;
xx = origin -- (xpart point infinity of wave, 0);
yy = origin -- (0, ypart point infinity of wave);
drawarrow xx;
drawarrow yy;

label.bot("Time"                 infont ff scaled 1.2,            point 1/2 of xx);
label.lft("Level of real output" infont ff scaled 1.2 rotated 90, point 1/2 of yy);
label.top("The business cycle"   infont ff scaled 1.44, point 0.8 of yy shifted 108 right) withcolor .8 red;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

compile this with `lualatex` to get a PDF looking like this:

[image]

### Note

If you have more than one `beginfig` / `endfig` pair in your source MP file, you should copy each of them into separate template files.

Comment: Lets say I have loaded `xelatex` and not `lualatex`, what changes should I make for the code to run?

Comment: You can't use `luamplib` with `xelatex`, but you can use `lualatex` to make a stand alone PDF and include that in your main document with `\includegraphics`

Comment: Noted with many thanks. Lets say I want to change the font type to times new roman, which commands should I add to achieve that?

Comment: For tutorials on MP have a look [here](https://tug.org/metapost.html).  For the specifics of handling text in MP see chapters 11 and 12 of [this](https://github.com/thruston/Drawing-with-Metapost).

Comment: But to change to Times in the above example, just change "phvr8r" to "ptmr8r".

Comment: Thank you very much @Thruston.