# Plotting one period of f(x)=tan x with the vertical asymptotes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to have the picture look like the hand drawing.Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.
[image: The graph of Tangent]

Comment: you can use metapost, geogebra or texgraph

Comment: I should have specified that I am trying to do it using tikz-pgf

Comment: with geogebra or texgraph you can convert to tikz

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/create-xkcd-style-diagram-in-tex

Comment: Please show us, what have you tried that isn't working? Most times, people don't like to answer questions that feel like "Do this thing for me", instead prefer to answer questions that are more like "I'm stuck with this small aspect, how can I accomplish it?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
        [
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    xmin=-2,xmax=2,
    %clip=false,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick={-8,-6,...,8},
    extra x ticks={-1.5708, 1.5708},
    extra x tick labels={$-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$},
    every extra x tick/.style={
            xticklabel style={anchor=north west},
            grid=major,
            major grid style={thick,dashed,red}
    },
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    domain=-.5*pi:.5*pi,
    samples=200,
    ]
        \addplot [red,thick] {tan(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you wish to give its chance to MetaPost, here is an example, included in a LuaLaTeX program, of what it can do with your problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=1bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibnumbersystem{double}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef function(expr xmin, xmax, xstep)(text f_x) =
    save x; x := xmin;
    (x, f_x) forever:
        hide(x := x + xstep)
        exitif x > xmax;
        .. (x, f_x) 
    endfor
    if x - xstep < xmax: hide(x := xmax) .. (x, f_x) fi
enddef;
numeric u, xmin, xmax, Xmin, Xmax, xstep, ymin, ymax;
u = 1.5cm; Xmax = -Xmin = 2.25; Ymax = -Ymin = 4.75; xstep = 0.05; xmax = -xmin = 1.5;

beginfig(1);
    draw function(xmin, xmax, xstep)(tan x) scaled u;
    clip currentpicture to 
        ((Xmin, Ymin) -- (Xmax, Ymin) -- (Xmax, Ymax) -- (Xmin, Ymax) -- cycle) scaled u;
    draw u*(-pi/2, Ymin) -- u*(-pi/2, Ymax) dashed evenly;
    draw u*(pi/2, Ymin) -- u*(pi/2, Ymax) dashed evenly;
    drawarrow u*(Xmin, 0) -- u*(Xmax, 0);
    drawarrow u*(0, Ymin) -- u*(0, Ymax);
    label.bot("$x$", (Xmax*u, 0)); label.lft("$y$", (0, Ymax*u)); 
    label.ulft("$O$", origin);
    label.llft("$-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$", (-u*pi/2, 0)); 
    label.llft("$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$", (u*pi/2, 0));
    labeloffset := 6bp;
    for i = -4 upto 4: 
        if i<>0: 
            draw (-3bp, i*u) -- (3bp, i*u); label.lft("$" & decimal i & "$", (0, i*u)); 
        fi 
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this does'nt answer the question.

Comment: @touhami Strictly speaking, yes it does: ‘‘I would like to have the picture look like the hand drawing. Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.’’ I know my solution does not use the OP's required package, but in general people here appreciate as well to see how the same drawing can be done with other graphical solutions. It can also help to improve the solutions given with the desired package, by emulation. What is really missing here is an example of coding given by the OP's, even rudimentary, showing how he had first tackled the problem…

Comment: @touhami: As fpast said, it's generally accepted (and encouraged) to post answers that use different approaches or packages than what is requested by the asker (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/downvoting-answers-exploiting-different-approaches-with-respect-to-the-initial-q). In a way, answers aren't just for the benefit of the asker, but for the general community, and it's definitely instructive to see different approaches for achieving the same outcome.

Comment: @fpast and jake (+1) you are right and the answer is welcom. I wanted to direct your attention to the question may have missed something (excuse my bad english)