# problem with plotting y=tan(x)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

Καλημέρα!

I 'm trying to draw the curve *y=tan(x)*.

- When I draw the curve at the domain *(-π/2,π/2)* everything is OK (see the 1st code and the image).
- When I draw the curve at other domains (e.g. `(π/2,3π/2)`) something goes bad (see the 2nd code and the image.

What is happening? How can I fix it?

***Domain=(-π/2,π/2)***

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xlabel style={below right},
ylabel style={above left},
xmin=-8.5,
xmax=8.5,
ymin=-8,
ymax=8,
xtick={-3*(pi/2),-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi,3*pi/2},
xticklabels={$-\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$}]
\addplot [domain=-pi/2:pi/2,ultra thick,smooth] {tan(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

***Domain=(-π/2,π/2)***

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xlabel style={below right},
ylabel style={above left},
xmin=-8.5,
xmax=8.5,
ymin=-8,
ymax=8,
xtick={-3*(pi/2),-pi,-pi/2,0,pi/2,pi,3*pi/2},
xticklabels={$-\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$}]
\addplot [domain=pi/2:3*pi/2,ultra thick,smooth] {tan(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Ευχαριστώ εκ των προτέρων!

Comment: Plotting is done by evaluating several values inside the given domain and then connecting the dots with straight segments. The number of values is controlled by the `samples=` option. Now as the tangent function has vertical asymptotes at 90° (and then every 180° of course), this will yield a very large value shortly before 90° and a very small (very negative) value shortly after. As a consequence, this gives an almost vertical line as an artifact. To fix it, you will need to draw the different parts separately.

Comment: I know this problem, so I draw the different parts separately. The problem is that the part with domain *(-π/2,π/2)*, isOK, but the part with domain *(π/2,3π/2)*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to get the desired result is to add the `restrict y to domain` key and set proper values.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xlabel style={below right},
        ylabel style={above left},
        xmin=-8.5,
        xmax=8.5,
        ymin=-8,
        ymax=8,
        smooth,
        restrict y to domain=-10:10,    % <-- added
    ]
        \addplot [domain=pi/2:3*pi/2,thick]         {tan(deg(x))};
        \addplot [domain=-pi/2:pi/2,ultra thick]    {tan(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[axis line style = very thick,
ymin=-4,ymax=4,
xmin=-2,xmax=5.5,
%clip=false,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
extra x ticks={-1.5708, 1.5708, 4.71239},
extra x tick labels={$-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$},
every extra x tick/.style={
    xticklabel style={anchor=north west},
    grid=major,
    major grid style={thick,dashed,black}
},
axis lines = center,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
domain=-.5*pi:.5*pi,
samples=200,
]
\addplot [black,ultra thick] {tan(deg(x))};
\addplot [domain=pi/2:3*pi/2,ultra thick] {tan(deg(x))};
\node at (axis cs:0.2, -0.28) {$O$} ;
\node at (axis cs:3.14, -0.28) {$\pi$} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I saw at here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233082/plotting-one-period-of-fx-tan-x-with-the-vertical-asymptotes