# Can a similar figure be drawn using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can a picture like this (not necessarily a kitten. Any simple figure would do) be drawn using Tikz? I don't have an MWE because I don't know where to start. 
[image]

Comment: You can start here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/create-xkcd-style-diagram-in-tex and here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines

Comment: Yes, it can. :)

Comment: @Alenanno Okay, I'll ask it. :) Will you please tell me how?

Comment: The center diagram can be generated as a series of dot pairs connected by \draw (A) -| (B); etc.  Some dots are used more than once.