# Handwritten slides presentation

Tags: presentations, slideshow

I want a slide presentation pdf like the one given [here](https://folk.ntnu.no/gereonq/Presentation_NMF_Bergen_2018.pdf). I'm very grateful if anyone can tell how to make it and/or give a template for it. But I don't know if it is made by LaTeX; so if it is produced by some other thing, please tell me what it is, then I can learn how to use it.

Comment: Maybe similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/create-xkcd-style-diagram-in-tex?

Comment: that was made with keynote https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keynote_(presentation_software)