# Unregular plot using latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there a way tp produce a similar plot in latex

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something that looks like xkcd style? Previously asked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/create-xkcd-style-diagram-in-tex also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39296/119

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Thanks