# Drawing a box around certain parts of a matrix

Tags: matrices, framed, highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix)

i have a matrix:

```
\begin{equation} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\label{e:crop1}
\end{equation}
```

and i would like to draw a box around a few of the values to highlight a selection & label it, how would i go about this?

I've looked at nodes but havent got a clue. thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you want the box to be around one element, or around a group of elements (e.g. column or 2x2 submatrix)? The first can be solved by putting `\fbox{4}` instead of just `4`.

Comment: Hi.  There are plenty of good questions on this already here. See e.g. [How to highlight elements in the matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/2693) and [How to highlight at single element in a matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60585/2693).

Comment: Please tell us then (in a comment) which question matched your question best and could be linked as a duplicate, if meaningful.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333011/draw-a-box-around-matrix-elements is a similar question.