# Draw a box around matrix elements

Tags: matrices

I studied the examples in [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix) and developed my example:

[image]

The code is the following:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells, ]
           {
         0    & -26  & 111 & 5  & -1     & 2    \\
         2666 & 67   & 55  & 77 & 6      & -1   \\
         -1   & 3    & 3   & 3  & 3      & 8    \\
         1    & 2    & 5   & 77 & 7      & 1    \\
         1    & 33   & 44  & 66 & 998888 & -266 \\
         -2   & 1    & 7   & -1 & 2      & 80   \\
       } ;
       \draw (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-2-1.south west) -- (m-2-2.south east) -- (m-1-2.north east) -- cycle;

     \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

What I do not like is that the box is skew.

Another feature that I do not like is that the column widths are not equal - the width of the column containing 998888 is larger.

Is it possible to control these aspects?

I would like to stick to tikz because it has an attractive feature - being able to draw a dotted line across multiple columns/rows (not addressed in the above example).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

It's important to understand that a `TikZ-matrix` only aligns inner nodes but it doesn't change nodes' size. It's esay to understand if you `draw` all nodes:

[image]

As you can see every node has its own size, being them into a `matrix` only distribute them in rows and columns. So the command

```
\draw (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-2-1.south west) -- (m-2-2.south east) 
       -- (m-1-2.north east) -- cycle;
```

will produce a skewed rectangle.

If you don't want to modify your code the easiest solution could be:

```
\draw (m-1-1.north-|m-1-2.west) rectangle (m-2-1.east|-m-2-2.south);
```

You can also force all nodes to have same width with an option like `text width={width(998888)}` which can be accompained by `align=right` and all nodes will be verticaly aligned to the right in every column.

```
nodes={text width={width(998888)}, align=right}
```

With this option you could use `draw (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-2-2.south east)` to define the desired region.

The coplete code is:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={text width={width(998888)}, align=right} ]
           {
         0    & -26  & 111 & 5  & -1     & 2    \\
         2666 & 67   & 55  & 77 & 6      & -1   \\
         -1   & 3    & 3   & 3  & 3      & 8    \\
         1    & 2    & 5   & 77 & 7      & 1    \\
         1    & 33   & 44  & 66 & 998888 & -266 \\
         -2   & 1    & 7   & -1 & 2      & 80   \\
       } ;
       \draw (m-1-1.north-|m-2-1.west) rectangle (m-2-2.east|-m-2-2.south);

     \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The rectangle of the example can be easily drawn by specifying opposite corners:

```
\draw (m-2-1.south west) rectangle (m-1-2.north east);
```

The general case is covered by Ignasi's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333053/16967).

The nodes can be set with a minimum width of the largest entry:

```
minimum width=width("998888")
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m)[
    matrix of math nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    minimum width=width("998888"),
  ] {
    0    & -26  & 111 & 5  & -1     & 2    \\
    2666 & 67   & 55  & 77 & 6      & -1   \\
    -1   & 3    & 3   & 3  & 3      & 8    \\
    1    & 2    & 5   & 77 & 7      & 1    \\
    1    & 33   & 44  & 66 & 998888 & -266 \\
    -2   & 1    & 7   & -1 & 2      & 80   \\
  } ;

  \draw (m-2-1.south west) rectangle (m-1-2.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

It's rather easy with `pstricks`: use an ordinary `bmatrix` enclosed in a `postscript` environment, put two empty nodes A and B at the relevant places, and join them with an `\ncbox` command with the convenient size parameters. A second solution (more of an automatic solution) consists in drawing a `\psframe` which joins two diagonally opposed nodes:

```
\documentclass[12pt, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{postscript}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & -26\pnode{C} & 111 & 5 & -1 & 2 \\
      \:\pnode[-0.05,0]{A} 2666 & 67\pnode[0.25, 0]{B} & 55 & 77 & 6 & -1 \\
      -1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 8 \\
      1 & 2 & 5 & 77 & 7 & 1 \\
      1 & 33 & 44 & 66 & \medmath{998888} & -266 \\
      -2 & 1 & 7 & -1 & 2 & 80
    \end{bmatrix}
    \ncbox[boxheight=0.85, boxdepth=0.1, linecolor=IndianRed]{A}{B}
  \end{postscript}
\end{equation*}
\smallskip

\begin{equation*}
\psset{linearc =0.2,linejoin=1}
 \begin{postscript}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      0 &-26\: \pnode[0,0.35]{C} & 111 & 5 & -1 & 2 \\
      \,\pnode[0,-0.1]{A}\:2666 & 67 & 55 & 77 & 6 & -1 \\
      -1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 8 \\
      1 & 2 & 5 & 77 & 7 & 1 \\
      1 & 33 & 44 & 66 & \medmath{998888} & -266 \\
      -2 & 1 & 7 & -1 & 2 & 80
    \end{bmatrix}
    \psframe[linecolor=IndianRed](A)(C)
  \end{postscript}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a solution that provides an automatic height of the box? Doing that manually seems to me a little bit archaic with Latex.

Comment: @pzorba75: Yes, more or less. As you can see, I used only two nodes (that's what `\ncbox` is done for), whereas we have to enclose 4 values in a frame. We also can use two nodes, in  positions `(2,1)` and `(1,2)`. What can't be fully automated is the vertical offset of these nodes. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`, which, as the Tikz library `matrix` does, create a PGF/Tikz node under each of the matrix (if you need them...).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[r,left-margin=0.6em]
    \Block[draw]{2-3}{}
    0    & -26  & 111 & 5  & -1     & 2    \\
    2666 & 67   & 55  & 77 & 6      & -1   \\
    -1   & 3    & 3   & 3  & 3      & 8    \\
    1    & 2    & 5   & 77 & 7      & 1    \\
    1    & 33   & 44  & 66 & 998888 & -266 \\
    -2   & 1    & 7   & -1 & 2      & 80   \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]