# How to plot Dirichlet Function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writting a document in maths and I want to add the graph of the Dirichlet Function.
I was googling to find the tikz code of something like that but unfortunately I found nothing...

The graph is what seems in the picture:
[image]

I don't know how to plot it in tikz... and a link I found https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/blob/master/tikz/dirichlet-function/dirichlet-function.tex

well while it was compiled... the graph was nowhere to be seen.

So, I would be more than happy if someone could provide me a link where I can copy the cody or draw that for me... I know it's a long shot!

Comment: It's this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75688/is-it-possible-to-combine-cases-with-pgfplots-legend . What is the condition for this plot? And how do you distinguish a real number from a rational on a computer?

Comment: BTW, as described in _e.g._ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html what you've put in as an image isn't actually the Dirichlet function.

Comment: Well that is what Google picture get.. when I type Dirichlet Function... !! Ok.. for the link.. apparentely I misunderstood..something.. so how do I draw tha graph on the pictue above that I posted?

Comment: That is the same as the "popcorn" function (Thomae's function), see p.56 of the documentation of `pst-func`. Can easily be changed to draw lines, if needed.

Comment: @Herbert Thank you although the result is not as nice the picture's above... But I think that will suit me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A modification of the popcorn function. `\psThomase@i` will be part of the next version of `pst-func`, hopefully.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\makeatletter
\def\psThomae@i(#1,#2)#3{%
  \addbefore@par{dotsize=1pt}
  \begin@ClosedObj
  \addto@pscode{
    1 1 #3 {
      dup 
      /ipSave ED    % save loop value
      /ip ED        % dito
      1 1 #3 {      
        dup     
        /iqSave ED  % save loop value
        /iq ED      % dito
        { 
          iq 0 le { exit } if
          ip iq mod 
          /ip iq def
          /iq ED 
        } loop
        ip 1 eq { 
          /xVal ipSave iqSave div def
          xVal #1 ge { xVal #2 lt {
            \pst@number\pslinewidth SLW
            \pst@usecolor\pslinecolor xVal 1 iqSave div \tx@ScreenCoor            
            2 copy pop 0 moveto lineto } if } if
        } if
      } for 
    } for
  }%
  \end@ClosedObj%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=4cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.1,-0.2)(2.5,1.15)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(2.25,1.1)
    \psThomae[linewidth=1pt](0,2){200}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask you? the graph is ok... but pstrick does not compile... how can I fix it?

Comment: Run it with `xelatex` or use `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` and run it with `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>`