# Creating boxes with background in baposter

Tags: baposter

I am using the baposter package to create a  poster. One can have colored boxes, but I want to have my own background for each box (and not for the poster itself). Is it possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Exactly how are you making those boxes? Yesterday I had student who wanted something similar. Ended up changing `baposter.cls` such that `\headposter` can take a `background` option. It is a fairly simple addition.

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly clear what is being requested, so I will take a guess that you would like a background image under your box content.  My approach is to take that content and place it in a `\vbox` with the macro

```
\setbox0=\vbox{<content>}
```

Then, I place the background image under it with an `\ooalign`, as in

```
\ooalign{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\ht0]{example-image-A}\cr\box0}
```

I am not a `baposter` user and so don't know if the small border around the background image can be eliminated, or even how to place multiple boxes on a single poster.

Here is my MWE.  I just grabbed some box content from this question: [Fitting as a background to nodes in multiple pictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103070/fitting-as-a-background-to-nodes-in-multiple-pictures)

```
\documentclass[b3paper]{baposter}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{bgColorOne=blue!20!white,background=plain}{}{}{}{}
 \begin{posterbox}[textborder=none,headerborder=none,span=3,boxColorOne=white]{title}
\setbox0=\vbox{%
  \begin{align}
  x &=
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
   \node[circle,fill=red,minimum width=1cm] {}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
  +
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
   \node[circle,fill=cyan,minimum width=1cm] (first node) {}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \\
  y &=
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
   \node[circle,fill=red,minimum width=1cm] {}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
  +
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
   \node[circle,fill=cyan,minimum width=1cm] (second node) {}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
  +
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
   \node[circle,fill=green,minimum width=1cm] (third node) {}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{align}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[draw=red,fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.8,fit=(first node) (second node) (third node),rectangle] {};
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\ooalign{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\ht0]{example-image-A}\cr\box0}
 \end{posterbox}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I can actually remove the 5pt border around the background image, by loading my `verbatimbox` package and invoking the `\ooalign` as

```
\ooalign{\addvbuffer[-5pt]{\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics%
  [width=\dimexpr\textwidth+10pt\relax,height=\dimexpr\ht0+10pt\relax]{%
  example-image-A}}}\cr\box0}
```

There are very likely better ways to accomplish that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Actyally I needed just the following codes:

Comment: \documentclass[b3paper]{baposter}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
 \begin{poster}{bgColorOne=blue!20!white,background=plain}{}{}{}{}
  \begin{posterbox}[textborder=none,headerborder=none,span=3,boxColorOne=white]{title}
   \setbox0=\vbox{%
   \text{My Text}
    }
   \ooalign{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\ht0]{example-image-A}\cr\box0}
  \end{posterbox}
 \end{poster}
\end{document}

Comment: @Mary I'm pleased that you can employ it for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter version of what the user needed in my case. I'll post post it here for future reference

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey[ba]{posterbox}[baposter@box@]{background}{}
\presetkeys[ba]{posterbox}{
  background=white,
}{}
\patchcmd{\poster}{%
text justified] {\usebox{\baposter@content}};% <- important
}{
text justified, fill=\baposter@box@background] 
{\usebox{\baposter@content}};
}{\typeout{patched}}{\typeout{not patched}}
\makeatother
```

This enables the use of

```
\headerbox{title}{options}{contents}
```

where options can now include background=color