# tikz mathematics: matrices and operations with them

Tags: tikz-pgf, mathematics

This code draws a certain plot:

```
\documentclass{minimal}                                                                                                                                                                                     
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                                                                                                                                           
\usepackage{amsmath}                                                                                                                                                                                        
\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                                                            
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm/2]                                                                                                                                                                                
  \newcommand\phiprim{60}                                                                                                                                                                                   
  \newcommand\x0{0.5}                                                                                                                                                                                       
  \newcommand\y0{0.5}                                                                                                                                                                                       
  \pgfplothandlerlineto                                                                                                                                                                                     
  \pgfplotfunction{\r}{0, 0.01, ..., 1}
{\pgfpointxy{\r*(cos(\phiprim)*\x0 + sin(\phiprim)*\y0)}
{\r*(-sin(\phiprim)*\x0 + cos(\phiprim)*\y0}}   %this line could be redefined with matrix multiplication 
  \pgfusepath{stroke}                                                                                                                                                                                       
\end{tikzpicture}                                                                                                                                                                                           
\end{document}
```

I could make my code nicer if I could define in `tikz` matrices

[image]

and perform operations with them

[image]

How matrices can be defined and how can one perform matrix operations in `tikz`.
**Here I am interested in matrices only as mathematical objects with no intention to display them.**

Comment: Some ways of creating matrices are listed in [Where is the \matrix command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26447/124842). Or [Tikzpicture and matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117177/124842)

Comment: If a matrix is big enough to NEED matrix operations, you really don't want to use pgfmath!

Comment: Related, though not the same: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112599/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73543 There is some support for array-like structures, see section 89.3 in the manual, but I don't think anything like what you're asking for is built in.

Comment: In a case where complicated mathematical expressions are needed to draw a plot, what would one use?

Comment: I am not sure --- are you looking for using a generic transformation matrix on the `tikz` coordinates? There is a `\pgftransformcm{a}{b}{c}{d }{point}` that do that. See the tikz manual, pag. 1047 in my copy, section 102.2.2 "commands for relative coordinates transformation":

Comment: Hmmm... `\def\x0{0.5}` doesn't do what you suspect. `\y0` is not a valid TeX macro name.

Comment: @JohnKormylo TikZ maybe (in a path), but TeX no... in the OP snippet, `\x` and `\y` ar both `0`, and `\x0` is the string `00`. Try to put this into the `tikzpicture`: `\newcommand\x0{0.5}\newcommand\y0{0.5} \node {\x0,\y0};` (To be exact, in the path `let` operation, where `\x` is a kind-of a command that takes an argument...)