# Align TikZ node inside equation environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, vertical-alignment

I am trying to insert a `TikZ` node into an equation but I have some problems:

1. the = sign is not vertically centred inside the circle
2. the circle is not vertically aligned with the formula. I want to abtain the same alignment of the first equation but I failed also using the `baseline` option
3. the equal sign must be at same distance from `)` as in the first equation

> **SOLUTIONS**

1. UNSOLVED
2. Solved in comments using `baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax`
3. UNSOLVED

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mathnodebase}{%
    \tikz[inner sep = 0pt,baseline]{\node[circle,draw=black] (1) {$=$};}}
\newcommand{\mathnode}{%
    \tikz[inner sep = 0pt]{\node[circle,draw=black] (1) {$=$};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) =
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) \mathnodebase
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) \mathnode
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The credit for having found the right setting to vertically align elements drawn with TikZ in math mode goes to [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) (no surprise thus): see his comment [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59658/use-of-tikzpicture-matrix-in-align-or-gather-environment#comment126261_59660).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino thanks. This solves the second point.

Comment: Should the `=` in the circle have the spacing as the normal `=` or should the new symbol (including the circle) should have that spacing?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel the `=` in the circle should have the same spacing as the normal `=`. But the third point is not so important, the more important is the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single symbol like `=` the vertical alignment is easier reached with `baseline` and `anchor=base` (this means the baseline of the node will be vertically aligned at the *y* = 0 while `baseline` implicits `baseline=0pt`).

Though [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)’s [formula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59658/use-of-tikzpicture-matrix-in-align-or-gather-environment#comment126261_59660) is used here to get a node where the `=` sits vertically centered (the original box of TeX is not symmetrical).

An `overlay`ed circle is then placed at the `.center` of that node. The `overlay` option takes the circle out of the bounding box of that TikZ picture so that `\mathrel` works as if it was a single `=`.

The radius of the circle can be adjusted at will.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzeq}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \tikz[baseline]{
      \node[inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, anchor=base, text depth=+0pt, text height=\the\dimexpr2\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax, name=tikz@equal] {${=}$};
      \draw[overlay] (tikz@equal.center) circle [radius=+1ex];
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\[ \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) =       \]
\[ \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) \tikzeq \]

\[ a=b \tikzeq c = \tikzeq \]
\begin{gather} a = b \\ a \tikzeq b    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]