# tikz and limits

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I don't really know how to explain what I want to do other than giving you the code I wrote :

```
\varinjlim\limits_\cI \left( \begin{tikzpicture}
     \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=1em]{
         A & B     \\
         C & \null \\
     };
     \path[-stealth]
        (m-1-1) edge node [left]  {} (m-2-1)
                edge node [above] {} (m-1-2);
    \end{tikzpicture} \right) = C \coprod\limits_A B
```

The result I get is :

[image]

I want it to look like what you would expect it to look like i.e. no space under the diagram

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you turn the code snippet into a complete minimal example document? That makes it much easier for others to try and come up with a solution (answering questions is fun, completing test document preambles is not).

Comment: You have to set the baseline to the vertical center of the `tikzpicture`

Comment: @egreg! TikZ answer! Woo!

Comment: @Jake One has also to trim the bounding box.

Comment: it seems like this particular example could be done without `tikz` though (*ducks, and runs for cover*)

Comment: @cmhughes: You mean one could use PSTricks or Asymptote? (Kidding!)

Comment: @Jake You (and we) people won't have work very soon ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the baseline of the `tikzpicture` to the vertical center of it; also it's better to use `left delimiter` and `right delimiter` rather than `\left` and `\right`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\varinjlim\limits_{\mathcal{I}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \matrix (m) [
    matrix of math nodes,
    row sep=1em,
    column sep=1em,
    left delimiter=(,
    right delimiter=),
  ]{
    A & B \\
    C \\
   };
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [left]  {} (m-2-1)
            edge node [above] {} (m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
= C \underset{A}{\amalg} B
\]
\end{document}
```

I changed `\cI` into `\mathcal{I}`, just a guess; also `\coprod` should not be used as a binary operator. If you really want to set the subscript underneath `\amalg` use `\underset`.

[image]

With the corrections suggested by Qrrbrbirlbel:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\varinjlim\limits_{\mathcal{I}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2]
  \matrix (m) [
    matrix of math nodes,
    row sep=1em,
    column sep=1em,
    outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,
    nodes={inner sep=.3333em},
    left delimiter=(,
    right delimiter=),
  ]{
    A & B \\
    C \\
   };
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [left]  {} (m-2-1)
            edge node [above] {} (m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
= C \underset{A}{\amalg} B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to align the vertical center of the matrix to vertical center of the vertical center of the line, something like `baseline=-.5ex` or even [`-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59658/use-of-tikzpicture-matrix-in-align-or-gather-environment#comment126261_59660)? Maybe also adding `inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, nodes={inner sep=+.3333em}` to the node to make the delimiters closer to the content of the matrix.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks; it would be nice to have a separate option for removing the padding around the matrix, rather than setting `inner sep` to zero and resetting it for nodes to a value that must be guessed.

Comment: The `.3333em` value is the default one (also mentioned in the manual). However you can do: `nodes/.expanded={inner xsep={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}, inner ysep={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}}, inner sep=+0pt`, i.e. storing the current values in the `every node` style and then setting it to `0pt` just for the matrix. Of course, one could define also wrapper keys like `matrix inner xsep` and so on that do these, but this would go beyond a comment, I believe. Maybe it would even be better to set the matrix’ `inner sep` to `-.3333em` to get the delimiters even closer (like `array`s).

Answer (score 10):

the same without `tikZ`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\varinjlim\limits_{\mathcal{I}}
\left(\begin{array}{l}
  A\to B \\
  \,\downarrow \\
  C
\end{array}\right) = C \underset{A}{\amalg} B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the other answer because it used tikz which I'm used to work with but your answer is great too.