# Tikz on TexMaths/LibreOffice

Tags: tikz-pgf

I put the following into TexMaths in LibreOffice

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz \draw (0,0) circle (10pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and was complained of

```
C:\..\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty
!Missing $inserted.
<inserted text>
          $
1.9
```

Before this, I have tested that the TexMaths is working fine on simple LaTex commands. 
Any idea? Thanks help.

Comment: Do you have `\documentclass` too?

Comment: As far as I can tell, TeXMaths uses its own preamble and places any code you give it in a maths environment. Hence trying to use a different environment would cause LaTeX some problems.

Comment: @ChrisS: you _can_ use a `tikzpicture` inside maths environments (see [use of tikzpicture matrix in align or gather environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59658/13304)): the problem here, I think, is how to properly set the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested, you need to set the preamble right.

[image]

Go to "Preamble" and you'll see something like this:

[image]

Add `\usepackage{tikz}` and then you can just type `\tikz\draw (0,0) circle (10pt);` or

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (10pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In the main Texmaths window, not the Preamble window. the result is:

[image]

I am on Texmaths 0.39 and Libreoffice 4.2.2

Comment: Thanks your illustration. I have tried and with the Preamble, seems it was rendering. It flashed for a second but nothing comes out, though no complain either. Found the code snippet and re-opened to edit for options, still the same nothing. TexMaths 0.39 and LibreOffice 4.2.2 on MS-Windows. Thanks your time.

Comment: so you don't see the circle as in my last screenshot?

Comment: That's right. It tries to render but end up nothing.

Comment: @Rising (un)fortunately I don't have a Windows machine to test if it works there. i tried any kind of complex TikZ code on my machine (Linux) and they all work. Let's wait until someone else tries.

Comment: I thought your instruction was correct and problem was only matter of rendering. My TexMaths was rendering on dvipng. I took that off and put in dvisvgm instead, and it works immediately. Thanks much.

Comment: @Rising If it works for you please accept this answer by clicking on the tickmark under the vote count of the answer.