# Arrow from last line of equation to the first

Tags: equations, arrows

I would like to have something similar to the arrow in this picture:

[image: Equation with arrow]

Is this possible to include without a lot of coding? At the moment the code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& ^\text{1}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H}  \rightarrow {}^\text{2}\text{H} + \text{e}^+ + \nu \\
& ^\text{2}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H}  \rightarrow {}^\text{3}\text{He} + \gamma  \\
& ^\text{3}\text{He} + {}^\text{4}\text{He}  \rightarrow {}^\text{7}\text{Be} \\
& ^\text{7}\text{Be} + \text{p}  \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{B} + \gamma \\
& ^\text{8}\text{B}  \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{Be} + \nu + \text{e}^+ \\
& ^\text{8}\text{Be} \rightarrow \text{2}~ ^\text{4}\text{He}
\label{eq:ppkette3}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I tried some stuff with a box but did not get any usable results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

A possible solution with the famous `\tikzmark` macro:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture, 
 baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]% correct vertical alignment:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59658/use-of-tikzpicture-matrix-in-align-or-gather-environment/59660#comment126261_59660
 \node (#1) {};%
}
\tikzset{square arrow/.style={to path={(\tikztostart)-- ++(-0.5,0) |- (\tikztotarget)}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\tikzmark{ini} & ^\text{1}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H}  \rightarrow {}^\text{2}\text{H} + \text{e}^+ + \nu \\
               & ^\text{2}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H}  \rightarrow {}^\text{3}\text{He} + \gamma  \\
               & ^\text{3}\text{He} + {}^\text{4}\text{He}  \rightarrow {}^\text{7}\text{Be} \\
               & ^\text{7}\text{Be} + \text{p}  \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{B} + \gamma \\
               & ^\text{8}\text{B}  \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{Be} + \nu + \text{e}^+ \\
\tikzmark{end} & ^\text{8}\text{Be} \rightarrow \text{2}~ ^\text{4}\text{He}
\end{split}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[-stealth,square arrow] (end) to (ini);
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{eq:ppkette3}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

It requires two compilation runs.

To get an arrowhead matching with `\rightarrow`, it is possible to exploit the powerful `arrows.meta` library. Add

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
```

in the preamble and change:

```
\draw[-stealth,square arrow] (end) to (ini);
```

with

```
\draw[-{To[length=2.45pt]},square arrow] (end) to (ini);
```

The result will be:

[image]

Comment: I note that `\draw[->,square arrow] (end) to (ini);` would give you an arrowhead that matches the `\rightarrow`s but how do you get it to be exactly the same size?

Comment: @Thruston: you're right. Please, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can also do this using a plain `halign` with no interline skips and vertical rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\vcenter{\offinterlineskip\halign{&$#$\hfil\cr
\vrule height .6ex depth 6pt\mkern-1.67mu \to & \rm \mathord{{}^1H + {}^1H} \to \mathord{{}^2H + e^+ + \nu} \cr
\vrule height  9pt depth 6pt                  & \rm \mathord{{}^2H + {}^1H} \to {}^3He +\gamma \cr
\vrule height  9pt depth 6pt                  & \rm \mathord{{}^3He+ {}^4He} \to {}^7Be\cr
\vrule height  9pt depth 6pt                  & \rm \mathord{{}^7Be+ p} \to {}^8B+\gamma\cr
\vrule height  9pt depth 6pt                  & \rm \mathord{{}^8B} \to {}^8Be+\nu+e^+\cr
\vrule height  9pt depth -.6ex\mkern-.67mu 
\vrule height .6ex depth -.5ex width 1em \ 
& \rm \mathord{{}^8Be} \to {}^4He\cr
}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This has the small advantage that the arrow heads look the same. Note that the final horizontal line is actually drawn by a `\vrule`.

Answer (score 2):

[`tkz-linknodes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-linknodes) package is another option in case you accept to place the arrow on the right side of your equations.

Package objective is to

> easily create links between the lines of an environment as aligned or
>   still align by indicating the operation made between the two lines

Only three commands/environments are used `NodesList`, `AddNode` and `LinkNodes`. An example taken from package documentations looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-linknodes}
\begin{document}
\begin{NodesList}
\begin{align}
\boxed{ 3(x^2-3) =4 } \AddNode\\
x^2-3 =\frac{4}{3} \AddNode\\
\intertext{\hfil isolate the term with the variable \hfil}
x^2 =\frac{13}{3} \AddNode\\
\sqrt{x^2} =\sqrt{\frac{13}{3}} \AddNode\\
|x| =\sqrt{\frac{13}{3}} \AddNode\\
x =\pm\sqrt{\frac{13}{3}} \AddNode
\end{align}
\LinkNodes[margin=1cm]{$\div 3$}%
\LinkNodes[margin=1.5cm]{$+3$}%
\LinkNodes[margin=2.5cm]{$\sqrt{\ldots}$}
\LinkNodes[margin=3cm]{$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$}
\LinkNodes[margin=4.5cm]{we have two answers}
\end{NodesList}
\end{document}
```

and produces

[image]

Therefore, your example could be

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-linknodes}
 \begin{document}

\begin{NodesList}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& ^\text{1}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H}  \rightarrow {}^\text{2}\text{H} + \text{e}^+ + \nu \AddNode \\
& ^\text{2}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H}  \rightarrow {}^\text{3}\text{He} + \gamma  \\
& ^\text{3}\text{He} + {}^\text{4}\text{He}  \rightarrow {}^\text{7}\text{Be} \\
& ^\text{7}\text{Be} + \text{p}  \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{B} + \gamma \\
& ^\text{8}\text{B}  \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{Be} + \nu + \text{e}^+ \\
& ^\text{8}\text{Be} \rightarrow \text{2}~ ^\text{4}\text{He}\AddNode 
\label{eq:ppkette3}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\tikzset{ArrowStyle/.append style={<-}}
\LinkNodes[margin=4cm]{}
\end{NodesList}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `pst-node`, but you have to go the latex -> dvips -> pstopdf:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, pdf]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{pst-node}

 \begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:ppkette3}
\begin{aligned}
\pnode(0,0){F}& ^\text{1}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H} \rightarrow {}^\text{2}\text{H} + \text{e}^+ + \nu \\
& ^\text{2}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H} \rightarrow {}^\text{3}\text{He} + \gamma \\
& ^\text{3}\text{He} + {}^\text{4}\text{He} \rightarrow {}^\text{7}\text{Be} \\
& ^\text{7}\text{Be} + \text{p} \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{B} + \gamma \\
& ^\text{8}\text{B} \rightarrow{}^\text{8}\text{Be} + \nu + \text{e}^+ \\
\pnode(0,0){L}& ^\text{8}\text{Be} \rightarrow \text{2}~ ^\text{4}\text{He}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\ncbar[angle = 180,nodesep = 0.5em]{->}{L}{F}

\end{document}     \documentclass[10pt,a4paper, pdf]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{pst-node}

 \begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:ppkette3}
\begin{aligned}
\pnode(0,0){F}& ^\text{1}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H} \rightarrow {}^\text{2}\text{H} + \text{e}^+ + \nu \\
& ^\text{2}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H} \rightarrow {}^\text{3}\text{He} + \gamma \\
& ^\text{3}\text{He} + {}^\text{4}\text{He} \rightarrow {}^\text{7}\text{Be} \\
& ^\text{7}\text{Be} + \text{p} \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{B} + \gamma \\
& ^\text{8}\text{B} \rightarrow{}^\text{8}\text{Be} + \nu + \text{e}^+ \\
\pnode(0,0){L}& ^\text{8}\text{Be} \rightarrow \text{2}~ ^\text{4}\text{He}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\ncbar[angle = 180,nodesep = 0.5em]{->}{L}{F}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you accept to place the arrow on the right side of your equations, you can use `witharrows` and it's direct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows*}[format = l]
^\text{1}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H}  \rightarrow {}^\text{2}\text{H} + \text{e}^+ + \nu
\Arrow[tikz=<-,jump=5]{} \\
^\text{2}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H}  \rightarrow {}^\text{3}\text{He} + \gamma  \\
^\text{3}\text{He} + {}^\text{4}\text{He}  \rightarrow {}^\text{7}\text{Be} \\
^\text{7}\text{Be} + \text{p}  \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{B} + \gamma \\
^\text{8}\text{B}  \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{Be} + \nu + \text{e}^+ \\
^\text{8}\text{Be} \rightarrow \text{2}~ ^\text{4}\text{He}
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the first code]

You can change the shape of the arrow if you want (if you know the syntax of Tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows*}%
   [ format = l ,
     tikz-code = { \draw (#1) -- ++(5mm,0) |- (#2) ; } ]
^\text{1}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H}  \rightarrow {}^\text{2}\text{H} + \text{e}^+ + \nu
\Arrow[tikz=<-,jump=5]{} \\
^\text{2}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H}  \rightarrow {}^\text{3}\text{He} + \gamma  \\
^\text{3}\text{He} + {}^\text{4}\text{He}  \rightarrow {}^\text{7}\text{Be} \\
^\text{7}\text{Be} + \text{p}  \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{B} + \gamma \\
^\text{8}\text{B}  \rightarrow {}^\text{8}\text{Be} + \nu + \text{e}^+ \\
^\text{8}\text{Be} \rightarrow \text{2}~ ^\text{4}\text{He}
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the second code]