# Making an anti-clockwise circled arrow around a + sign in a math environment

Tags: math-mode, environments

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\@SizeOfCirc%
\newcommand{\CricArrowRight}[1]{%
\setlength{\@SizeOfCirc}{\maxof{\widthof{#1}}{\heightof{#1}}}%
\tikz [x=1.0ex,y=1.0ex,line width=.15ex, draw=black]%
\draw [->,anchor=center]%
node (0,0) {#1}%
(0,1.2\@SizeOfCirc) arc (-90:180:1.2\@SizeOfCirc);%
}%
\makeatother
```

This being in the premeable and the code below used in the document,

```
\begin{equation}
\CricArrowRight{+}\sum M_{z})_{o}&=0
\end{equation}
```

what I have produced is this,

[image]

but what I need to produce is the following:

[image]

Could you please help me write the equation above properly?

Answer (score 13):

The arc starts at `(0, 1.2\@SizeOfCirc)`, which is *above* the `+` sign. As you want it to start below the `+`, simply change the arc to start at `(0, -1.2\@SizeOfCirc)`.
This gives the following result:

[image: Result]

To position the symbol such that the `+` is aligned correctly, you'll have to change the `baseline` option of `\tikz` to `baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax`, as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59660/65692). The result then looks like this:

[image: End result]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}

\makeatletter
\newlength\@SizeOfCirc%
\newcommand{\CricArrowRight}[1]{%
\setlength{\@SizeOfCirc}{\maxof{\widthof{#1}}{\heightof{#1}}}%
\tikz [x=1.0ex,y=1.0ex,line width=.15ex, draw=black, baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]%
\draw [->,anchor=center]%
node (0,0) {#1}%
(0,-1.2\@SizeOfCirc) arc (-90:180:1.2\@SizeOfCirc);
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \CricArrowRight{+} \sum M_{z})_{o}=0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Done without `tikz`, by overlaying the `amsmath` symbol `\circlearrowleft` atop the argument.  The circled arrow is scaled and rotated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand\CircArrowLeft[1]{\stackengine{-.3ex}{#1}{\CAL}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand\CAL{\scalebox{2}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{$\circlearrowleft$}}}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\CircArrowLeft{+}\sum M_{z})_{o}=0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Similar to hbaderts' but with a bit of extras (e.g., `\DOTSB` for correct autopositioning of `\dots`, usage of `pgfmath` macros to calculate the width, etc.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,lmodern,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,bending}

\newcommand*\carr[1]
  {\DOTSB\mathbin{\mkern2mu\tikz[x=1ex, y=1ex, line width=.1ex, line cap=round, draw=black, baseline=-\the\fontdimen22\textfont2] {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\circlesize{max(width("$#1$"),height("$#1$"))*.8}
    \draw[->, >=stealth', anchor=center] node (0,0) {$#1$}
    ++(-100:\circlesize pt) arc (-100:195:\circlesize pt);}}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \Bigl( A \carr{+} \sum M_z \Bigr)_{0} = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. I think `*.8` might look better, such that it does not rival the size of the symmation symbol.

Comment: The angles of the arc is another thing to consider, I chose what I chose because it looked good with `+` but may be if one uses another symbol another values are better (the default `-90:180` might be the most general). @daleif That might be true (I edited the answer), in any case, it's quite easy to change the `*.8` by whatever one prefers.

Comment: @user82745 The way of saying thanks here is upvoting answers; and accepting the one that works better for you. In any case, you should change your username to something more telling than user12345.

Answer (score 2):

Another TikZ solution.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,bending}
\def\CricArrowRight#1{\tikz[baseline=(A.base)]
  \draw[-stealth,line width=.035em]
    (0,0) node[circle, inner sep=0cm](A){$#1$}
    let \p1=(A.center),\p2=(A.west), \n1={\x1-\x2} in
      (-90:\n1) arc(-90:190:\n1);}
\begin{document}
  $\CricArrowRight{+}\sum M_{z})_{o}=0$\\[1em]
  \CricArrowRight{+} \CricArrowRight{-} \CricArrowRight{\#}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,bending}
\def\CricArrowNCW#1{\tikz[baseline=(A.base)]
  \draw[-stealth,line width=.035em]
    (0,0) node[circle, inner sep=.05cm](A){$#1$}
    let \p1=(A.center),\p2=(A.west), \n1={\x1-\x2} in
      (90:\n1) arc(90:-190:\n1);}
      
\def\CricArrowACW#1{\tikz[baseline=(A.base)]
  \draw[-stealth,line width=.035em]
    (0,0) node[circle, inner sep=.05cm](A){$#1$}
    let \p1=(A.center),\p2=(A.west), \n1={\x1-\x2} in
      (-90:\n1) arc(-90:180:\n1);}


\begin{document}
  \CricArrowNCW{+} %normal clock wise
  \CricArrowACW{-} %  anti clock wise
\end{document}
```

[image: output =]

Comment: Hello old friend! Could you please point out in what way this answer differs from the one given by @Kpym below. Just adding a counter clockwise part by inverting the arc is not really enough to justify a new answer.