# Positioning a vertex directly above another vertex in feynMF

Tags: metapost, feynmf, metafont

I have been trying to replicate this Feynman diagram with feynMF. (Image from [1]). [image: Perturbative expansion of the dressed propagator.]

The first part, the double line, is rather easy, as it is already present in feynMF as the `heavy` style. For the crossed inside a circle, I used `\fmfcmd` to define a new style that I call `crossed` (I still haven't figured out how to reuse that without putting the style definition in each `\fmffile` environment, hence the verbosity of the code below).

Now, doing the obvious, i.e.

```
\begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
  \fmfleft{i1}
  \fmfright{o1}
  \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v2,o1}
  \fmffreeze   
  \fmftop{t1,t2}
  \fmf{crossed}{t1,v1}
  \fmf{crossed}{t2,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
```

results in the photon propagators to have an unpleasant looking angle (see the third diagram). [image: Angled photon propagators]

I have also tried to place vertices at specific locations, and then drawing the paths manually with the immedidate mode of feynMF, with limited success. I have tried the following snippet.

```
\begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
  \fmfleft{i1}
  \fmfright{o1}
  \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v2,o1}
  \fmffreeze
  \fmfipair{t1,t2}
  \fmfiequ{t1}{vloc(__v1) shifted (0,5mm)}
  \fmfiequ{t2}{vloc(__v2) shifted (0,5mm)}
  \fmfiv{d.sh=circle}{t1}
  \fmfiv{d.sh=circle}{t2}
  \fmfi{crossed}{vpath(__v1,__t1)}
  \fmfi{crossed}{vpath(__v2,t2)}
\end{fmfgraph*}
```

The reasoning is as follows. I draw the fermion line first, and define the vertices on this line using the automatic mode of feynMF, i.e. with `\fmfleft` and the other usual commands. Then, after calling `\fmffreeze`, I switch to using the immediate mode. Then I declare a METAFONT pair with `\fmfipair` and set to a value that is shifted from the vertices `v1` and `v2`. I then try to draw vertices at these locations and draw paths between `v1`, `v2` and the shifted vertices, `t1` and `t2`. The code, however, leads to a

```
! Illegal suffix of declared variable will be flushed.
<to be read again> 
               1
l.15 pair t1
        ,t2;
?
```

error. What's wrong with my use of the immediate mode? Or of METAFONT? Is there a more direct way of doing what I want?

For reference, I have included the complete code below.

P.-S. I have tried `tikz-feynman` and it can indeed be done easily with this package, but I do not like the way loops look and I have issues with the baseline when they are included in equations.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \node{
    \begin{fmffile}{dressed-propagator}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,20)
      \fmfleft{i1}
      \fmfright{o1}
      \fmf{heavy}{i1,o1}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
  };
 \path[use as bounding box] ([shift={(2.5ex,2.5ex)}]current bounding box.north east) rectangle ([shift={(-2.5ex,-2.5ex)}]current bounding box.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \node{
    \begin{fmffile}{classical-source}
      \fmfcmd{%
        vardef cross_bar (expr p, len, ang) =
          ((-len/2,0)--(len/2,0))
          rotated (ang + angle direction length(p)/2 of p)
          shifted point 0 of p shifted (0,1.5mm)
        enddef;
        style_def crossed expr p =
          cdraw (wiggly p);
          ccutdraw cross_bar (p, 3mm, 45);
          ccutdraw cross_bar (p, 3mm, -45);
          cdraw fullcircle scaled 3mm shifted point 0 of p shifted (0,1.5mm);
        enddef;}
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
        \fmfleft{i1}
        \fmfright{o1}
        \fmftop{t1}
        \fmf{fermion,tension=100}{i1,v1,o1}
        \fmf{crossed}{t1,v1}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
  };
 \path[use as bounding box] ([shift={(2.5ex,2.5ex)}]current bounding box.north east) rectangle ([shift={(-2.5ex,-2.5ex)}]current bounding box.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \node{
    \begin{fmffile}{classical-source-2}      
      \fmfcmd{%
        vardef cross_bar (expr p, len, ang) =
          ((-len/2,0)--(len/2,0))
          rotated (ang + angle direction length(p)/2 of p)
          shifted point 0 of p shifted (0,1.5mm)
        enddef;
        style_def crossed expr p =
          cdraw (wiggly p);
          ccutdraw cross_bar (p, 3mm, 45);
          ccutdraw cross_bar (p, 3mm, -45);
          cdraw fullcircle scaled 3mm shifted point 0 of p shifted (0,1.5mm);
        enddef;}
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
        \fmfleft{i1}
        \fmfright{o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v2,o1}
        \fmffreeze   
        \fmftop{t1,t2}
        \fmf{crossed}{t1,v1}
        \fmf{crossed}{t2,v2}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
  };
 \path[use as bounding box] ([shift={(2.5ex,2.5ex)}]current bounding box.north east) rectangle ([shift={(-2.5ex,-2.5ex)}]current bounding box.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
```

[1]: S. Meuren, (2015). Nonlinear quantum electrodynamic and electroweak processes in strong laser fields. http://archiv.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/volltextserver/18971/

Comment: You mention that you've had issues with [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) because of the loops and baselines.  The baselines can be adjusted with the `inline` option or even `baseline` option from Ti*k*Z, so I'm curious what your issue is.  Regarding the loops, I'm sorry you don't like how they look :/  You can probably customize that with some extra Ti*k*Z code though.  If you post these questions on TeX.SX, email me, or raise an issue on Github I'll take a look (PS: I created Ti*k*Z-Feynman).  Curiously, would you like me to still post a Ti*k*Z-Feynman answer?

Comment: @JP-Ellis The `baseline` issue is indeed a non-issue, just some fiddling required. I need to embed the diagrams in equations, and the direct result is [this](http://i.imgur.com/Pv4HLZT.png). I could of course align everything, it's not hard. The look of the loops is not your fault. I tried fiddling with the `looseness` parameter, but the way I see it, becasue of the path construction, it is hard to have a perfect circle in a loop diagram. Contrast what feynMF gives for the vacuum polarization diagram (http://i.imgur.com/f4vCMS3.png) to what TikZ-Feynman gives (http://i.imgur.com/FJC2MTo.png).

Comment: @JP-Ellis You can still the post the TikZ-Feynman for posterity, but you are right, it is trivially easy to do this with TikZ-Feynman: I just used the manual placement mode, with the `feynman` environment you provide. In fact, the loops are my only issue with TikZ-Feynman, other than the fact that I have to figure out how to add arbitrary decorations to vertices (although I think you provide the `crossed dot` decoration already! Great work! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simpler solution to this problem. To position the vertices on the two lines the same, position them using rows with the same pattern of tensions. Once they have positions use \fmffreeze to fix positions and add the vertical lines.

The horizontal line that is used to position the top vertices would want to be drawn as `phantom` so it's invisible but would position them using the same algorithms as in the drawn line at the bottom. Using phantom lines is a very powerful tool that can produce many complex diagrams in much easier methods.

It's also possible to have multiple diagrams in one fmffile and then you only need to declare the formats once.

```
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
    % Needed so that the different vertices down the side are directly above each other.
    \fmfstraight 
    \fmfleft{i0,i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o0,o1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v2,o1}
    \fmf{phantom}{i2,t1,t2,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{crossed}{t1,v1}
    \fmf{crossed}{t2,v2}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
```

The full example is below

```
\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
      \fmfcmd{%
        vardef cross_bar (expr p, len, ang) =
          ((-len/2,0)--(len/2,0))
          rotated (ang + angle direction length(p)/2 of p)
          shifted point 0 of p shifted (0,1.5mm)
        enddef;
        style_def crossed expr p =
          cdraw (wiggly p);
          ccutdraw cross_bar (p, 3mm, 45);
          ccutdraw cross_bar (p, 3mm, -45);
          cdraw fullcircle scaled 3mm shifted point 0 of p shifted (0,1.5mm);
        enddef;}
        \begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \node{
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,20)
      \fmfleft{i1}
      \fmfright{o1}
      \fmf{heavy}{i1,o1}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
  };
 \path[use as bounding box] ([shift={(2.5ex,2.5ex)}]current bounding box.north east) rectangle ([shift={(-2.5ex,-2.5ex)}]current bounding box.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \node{
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
        \fmfleft{i1}
        \fmfright{o1}
        \fmftop{t1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \fmffreeze
        \fmf{crossed}{t1,v1}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
  };
 \path[use as bounding box] ([shift={(2.5ex,2.5ex)}]current bounding box.north east) rectangle ([shift={(-2.5ex,-2.5ex)}]current bounding box.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \node{
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
        \fmfstraight
        \fmfleft{i0,i1,i2}
        \fmfright{o0,o1,o2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v2,o1}
        \fmf{phantom}{i2,t1,t2,o2}
        \fmffreeze
        \fmf{crossed}{t1,v1}
        \fmf{crossed}{t2,v2}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
  };
 \path[use as bounding box] ([shift={(2.5ex,2.5ex)}]current bounding box.north east) rectangle ([shift={(-2.5ex,-2.5ex)}]current bounding box.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{fmffile}
```

Output is here
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Although this answer doesn't user `feynmf`, this can be easily achieved in [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman).  The only trick is that you have to manually adjust the baseline of diagrams so that the horizontal lines line up with minus and equal signs.  Note that `lualatex` is required in order to exploit automatic positioning of vertices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to b, inline=-2.5pt] {
      a -- [double] b,
    };
    &= 
    \feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to b, inline=-2.5pt] {
      a -- b,
    };
    +
    \feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to b, inline=-2.5pt] {
      a -- b -- c,
      {[same layer] b -- [photon] bi [crossed dot]},
    };
    +
    \feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to b, inline=-2.5pt] {
      a -- b -- c -- d,
      {[same layer] b -- [photon] bi [crossed dot]},
      {[same layer] c -- [photon] ci [crossed dot]},
    }; \\ &\quad
    +
    \feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to b, inline=-2.5pt] {
      a -- b -- c -- d -- e,
      {[same layer] b -- [photon] bi [crossed dot]},
      {[same layer] c -- [photon] ci [crossed dot]},
      {[same layer] d -- [photon] di [crossed dot]},
    };
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I added a note about the use of `lualatex`, it's far from being clear and answers should be self-sufficient `;-)`.  In addition, for lining up the diagrams you don't need to do it manually, but there is the `-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax` trick by egreg that evaluates automatically to `-2.5pt` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59658#comment126261_59660).

Comment: Thanks for that :)  Also, thanks for letting me know of this trick!  I was looking for a way to do that more automatically.

Comment: Quick question, how would modify this code to have the photon above the electron line?

Comment: @JoeyDumont Replace `horizontal=` with `horizontal'=`.  The primed version causes an the whole graph to flipped.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out why the snippet above fails, but I have found a solution to my problem. The relevant snippet is

```
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
      % -- Declares the vertices to be used.
      \fmfleft{i1}
      \fmfright{o1}
      \fmftop{t1,t2}

      % -- Since we want the diagram to be a straight line,
      % -- we use \fmffreeze after drawing only the fermion line.
      \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v2,o1}
      \fmffreeze

      % -- We force the position of the top vertices to be directly
      % -- above the interaction vertices.
      \fmfforce{vloc(__v1) shifted (0,10mm)}{t1}
      \fmfforce{vloc(__v2) shifted (0,10mm)}{t2}

      % -- We finally draw the paths.
      \fmf{crossed}{t1,v1}
      \fmf{crossed}{t2,v2}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
```

This results in the following image, which is the desired image.

[image: Resummation of the external fied.]

The use of `\fmfforce` and `\fmfshift` are described as last resort in the `feynmf` [documentation](http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/fmfman.pdf), but I think this qualifies, as the use of a skeleton results in the diagrams shown in the original question.

The complete code is, for completeness:

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \node{
      \begin{fmffile}{dressed-propagator}
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,20)
        \fmfleft{i1}
        \fmfright{o1}
        \fmf{heavy}{i1,o1}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
      \end{fmffile}
    };
 \path[use as bounding box] ([shift={(2.5ex,2.5ex)}]current bounding box.north east) rectangle ([shift={(-2.5ex,-2.5ex)}]current bounding box.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
=
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \node{
      \begin{fmffile}{classical-source}
        \fmfcmd{%
          vardef cross_bar (expr p, len, ang) =
            ((-len/2,0)--(len/2,0))
            rotated (ang + angle direction length(p)/2 of p)
            shifted point 0 of p shifted (0,1.5mm)
          enddef;
          style_def crossed expr p =
            cdraw (wiggly p);
            ccutdraw cross_bar (p, 3mm, 45);
            ccutdraw cross_bar (p, 3mm, -45);
            cdraw fullcircle scaled 3mm shifted point 0 of p shifted (0,1.5mm);
          enddef;
      }
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
        \fmfleft{i1}
        \fmfright{o1}
        \fmftop{t1}
        \fmf{fermion,tension=100}{i1,v1,o1}
        \fmf{crossed}{t1,v1}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
    };
    \path[use as bounding box] ([shift={(2.5ex,2.5ex)}]current bounding box.north east) rectangle ([shift={(-2.5ex,-2.5ex)}]current bounding box.south west);
 \end{tikzpicture}
+
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
   \node{
     \begin{fmffile}{classical-source-2}
       \fmfcmd{%
         vardef cross_bar (expr p, len, ang) =
           ((-len/2,0)--(len/2,0))
           rotated (ang + angle direction length(p)/2 of p)
           shifted point 0 of p shifted (0,1.5mm)
         enddef;
         style_def crossed expr p =
           cdraw (wiggly p);
           ccutdraw cross_bar (p, 3mm, 45);
           ccutdraw cross_bar (p, 3mm, -45);
           cdraw fullcircle scaled 3mm shifted point 0 of p shifted (0,1.5mm);
        enddef;
      }
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
        \fmfleft{i1}
        \fmfright{o1}
        \fmftop{t1,t2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v2,o1}
        \fmffreeze
        \fmfforce{vloc(__v1) shifted (0,10mm)}{t1}
        \fmfforce{vloc(__v2) shifted (0,10mm)}{t2}
        \fmf{crossed}{t1,v1}
        \fmf{crossed}{t2,v2}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
  };
    \path[use as bounding box] ([shift={(2.5ex,2.5ex)}]current bounding box.north east) rectangle ([shift={(-2.5ex,-2.5ex)}]current bounding box.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
```