# How can I type this form of a matrix in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

[image]
How can I type this form of a matrix in LaTeX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [kbordermatrix package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/kbordermatrix). (I think for licence reasons it cannot be included in the TeX distributions.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}
\[ C = \raisebox{-2\baselineskip}{%
   \begin{tabular}[b]{c@{\hspace*{0.5em}}c}
   & To node
   \\
     \begin{sideways}
       From node
     \end{sideways}
   & \raisebox{0.5\height}%
       {\(\kbordermatrix
            { &  1  &   2 &  3  &  4  &  5  \\
            1 &  1  & x_1 & x_5 &  0  &  0 \\
            2 & x_1 &  1  & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \\
            3 & x_5 & x_2 &  1  & x_6 &  0  \\
            4 &  0  & x_3 & x_6 &  1  & x_7 \\
            5 &  0  & x_4 &  0  & x_7 & 1
            }
        \)%
       }
   \end{tabular}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `kbordermatrix` is included in MiKTeX distribution...

Answer (score 7):

Something similar can be done with TikZ.  The baseline correction of the matrix is achieved by means of [egreg’s formula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59658/use-of-tikzpicture-matrix-in-align-or-gather-environment#comment126261_59660).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\[
C =
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]M.center)}]
  \matrix [
    matrix of math nodes,
    left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]},
    inner sep=1pt, column sep=1ex, row sep=1ex,
    execute at begin cell=\mathstrut,
  ] (M) {
    1 & x_1 & x_5 &  0  &  0 \\
    x_1 &  1  & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \\
    x_5 & x_2 &  1  & x_6 &  0  \\
    0  & x_3 & x_6 &  1  & x_7 \\
    0  & x_4 &  0  & x_7 & 1 \\
  };

  \foreach \c in {1,...,5}
    \node[above=1em] at (M-1-\c) {$\scriptstyle\c$};
  \foreach \r in {1,...,5}
    \node[left=1.5em] at (M-\r-1) {$\scriptstyle\r$};

  \node[above=2em] at (M-1-3) {To node};

  \node[rotate=90,above=2.5em] at (M-3-1) {From node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]