# Equations including ``tikzpicture`` II

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations

I'm using the same codes as my the answer of my previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602750/equations-including-tikzpicture)

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    D &=
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax,
    strip/.style = {
        draw=#1,%color
        line width=1em, opacity=0.2,
        shorten <=-2mm,shorten >=-2mm,
                                },
                        ]
    \matrix (mtrx)  [matrix of math nodes,
                     column sep=1em,
                     nodes={text height=1ex,text width=2ex},
                     ampersand replacement=\&]
    {
    |[red]|+  \& |[red]|+  \& |[red]| +
     \\[3.3mm,between origins]
    a_1 \& b_1 \& c_1 \& a_1 \& a_2         \\
    a_2 \& b_2 \& c_2 \& a_2 \& b_2         \\
    a_3 \& b_3 \& c_3 \& a_3 \& b_3         \\
    |[blue]|- \& |[blue]|- \& |[blue]|- \\
    };
    \draw[thick]  (mtrx-4-1.south west) -- (mtrx-2-1.north west);
    \draw[thick] (mtrx-4-3.south east)  -- (mtrx-2-3.north east);
    \path[draw,strip=blue]
        (mtrx-4-1.center) edge (mtrx-2-3.center)
        (mtrx-4-2.center) edge (mtrx-2-4.center)
        (mtrx-4-3.center)  --  (mtrx-2-5.center);
    \path[draw,strip=red]
        (mtrx-2-1.center) edge (mtrx-4-3.center)
        (mtrx-2-2.center) edge (mtrx-4-4.center)
        (mtrx-2-3.center)  --  (mtrx-4-5.center);
    \end{tikzpicture} \\
     &= a+b+c\dots
    \end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

However I want to replace

[image]

If I replace in the codes

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax,
strip/.style = {
    draw=#1,%color
    line width=1em, opacity=0.2,
    shorten <=-2mm,shorten >=-2mm,
                            },
                    ]
\matrix (mtrx)  [matrix of math nodes,
                 column sep=1em,
                 nodes={text height=1ex,text width=2ex},
                 ampersand replacement=\&]
{
|[red]|+  \& |[red]|+  \& |[red]| +
 \\[3.3mm,between origins]
a_1 \& b_1 \& c_1 \& a_1 \& a_2         \\
a_2 \& b_2 \& c_2 \& a_2 \& b_2         \\
a_3 \& b_3 \& c_3 \& a_3 \& b_3         \\
|[blue]|- \& |[blue]|- \& |[blue]|- \\
};
\draw[thick]  (mtrx-4-1.south west) -- (mtrx-2-1.north west);
\draw[thick] (mtrx-4-3.south east)  -- (mtrx-2-3.north east);
\path[draw,strip=blue]
    (mtrx-4-1.center) edge (mtrx-2-3.center)
    (mtrx-4-2.center) edge (mtrx-2-4.center)
    (mtrx-4-3.center)  --  (mtrx-2-5.center);
\path[draw,strip=red]
    (mtrx-2-1.center) edge (mtrx-4-3.center)
    (mtrx-2-2.center) edge (mtrx-4-4.center)
    (mtrx-2-3.center)  --  (mtrx-4-5.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \matrix [%
      matrix of math nodes,
      column sep=1em,
      row sep=1em
    ] (sarrus) {%
      a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{11} & a_{12} \\
      a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{21} & a_{22} \\
      a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{31} & a_{32} \\
    };

    \path ($(sarrus-1-1.north west)-(0.5em,0)$) edge ($(sarrus-3-1.south west)-(0.5em,0)$)
          ($(sarrus-1-3.north east)+(0.5em,0)$) edge ($(sarrus-3-3.south east)+(0.5em,0)$)
          (sarrus-1-1)                          edge            (sarrus-2-2)
          (sarrus-2-2)                          edge[->]        (sarrus-3-3)
          (sarrus-1-2)                          edge            (sarrus-2-3)
          (sarrus-2-3)                          edge[->]        (sarrus-3-4)
          (sarrus-1-3)                          edge            (sarrus-2-4)
          (sarrus-2-4)                          edge[->]        (sarrus-3-5)
          (sarrus-3-1)                          edge[dashed]    (sarrus-2-2)
          (sarrus-2-2)                          edge[->,dashed] (sarrus-1-3)
          (sarrus-3-2)                          edge[dashed]    (sarrus-2-3)
          (sarrus-2-3)                          edge[->,dashed] (sarrus-1-4)
          (sarrus-3-3)                          edge[dashed]    (sarrus-2-4)
          (sarrus-2-4)                          edge[->,dashed] (sarrus-1-5);

    \foreach \c in {1,2,3} {\node[anchor=south] at (sarrus-1-\c.north) {$+$};};
    \foreach \c in {1,2,3} {\node[anchor=north] at (sarrus-3-\c.south) {$-$};};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

It does not work.

Comment: In the previous code there is `ampersand replacement=\&`. Could be this the problem?

Comment: And you can have a look at [this one too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549490/204164).

Comment: Just like with my code, you need to use `ampersand replacement` (as already mentioned by @vipa), and in addition you need to remove the empty lines. Didn't think about that earlier, but empty lines are not allowed in math environments. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230338/

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I replaced ``\&=`` by ``=\&`` but it does not complile

Comment: Huh? That has nothing to do with what I said above. Did you remove the empty lines before `\path` and `\foreach`?  Did you add `ampersand replacement=\&` to the options of the `matrix`?

Comment: Don't use `\&` outside the `tikzpicture`, only inside.

Comment: I'm so sorry @TorbjørnT. since I tired you. I will be really greatful if you add this answer to the answer of your previous question. I deleted empty lines but I don't understand how to add ``ampersand replacement=\&`` to the options of the matrix

Comment: Please look at the code in my original answer - where in that code do you find `ampersand replacement`? "Options" in this context is the list of settings that you add in `[]` after `\matrix`.

Comment: Yes I added it and I'm trying to compilate but till now it does not work.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The error message indicate that there is ``$``. I removed ``$`` but it does not work also.

Comment: Look, I'm not at my computer now, but meanwhile, compare the `tikzpicture` from my code with your new one, and change the new one accordingly. I cannot guess how you managed to get an error about dollar signs.

Comment: Since 4 hours I'm trying. I will be very greatful if you can help me later. Not necessarely today

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I followed all your recommondations. The error message is long ``l.37 \end{align*}
                 
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 
                                             
l.37 \end{align*}
                 
? 
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.37 \end{align*}
                 
? ``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126914/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-student).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fun, another way using `blkarray`, an `align*` environment and `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
D & = \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
  \color{red} + & \color{red} + & \color{red} + \\
\begin{block}{|ccc|cc}
\Rnode{a1}{a_{11}} &\Rnode{b1}{ a_{12}} & \Rnode{c1}{a_{13}} & \Rnode{A1}{a_{11}} & \Rnode{B1}{a_{12}} \\
\Rnode{a2}{ a_{21}} & \Rnode{b2}{a_{22}} & \Rnode{c2}{a_{23}} & \Rnode{A2}{a_{21} }& a_{22} \\
  \Rnode{a3}{a_{31}} & \Rnode{b3}{a_{32}} & \Rnode{c3}{a_{33}} & \Rnode{A3}{a_{31}} & \Rnode{B3}{a_{32}} \\
\end{block}
  \color{blue} - & \color{blue} - & \color{blue} -
\end{blockarray} \\[-3ex]
& = a_{11} a_{22}a_{33} + a_{12}a_{23}a_{31} + \dots
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt, nodesepA=1pt, nodesepB =1.5pt, arrowinset=0.1}
\foreach \s/\t in {a1/b2,b1/c2,c1/A2} {\ncline{-}{\s}{\t}}
\foreach \s/\t in {b2/c3,c2/A3,A2/B3} {\ncline{->}{\s}{\t}}
\psset{linestyle=dashed, dash=3pt 2pt}
\foreach \s/\t in {a3/b2,b3/c2,c3/A2} {\ncline{-}{\s}{\t}}
\foreach \s/\t in {b2/c1,c2/A1,A2/B1} {\ncline{->}{\s}{\t}}
   %
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Professor for your great answer but I fails to compilate

Comment: @Student: How did you compile?

Comment: I just copy and paste your codes but I does not work

Comment: l.26 \end{align*}
                 
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.26 \end{align*}
                 
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@ 
                                                  \fi \space 
l.26 \end{align*}
                 
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.26 \end{align*}

Comment: the error message is so long

Comment: You have to know that pdflatex can't compile pstricks code, because it doesn't have the  necessary tools to make the computations required  by postscript. The basic way is `latex > dvips > pstopdf`. Simpler: compile with `xelatex -shell-escape`.

Comment: I'm sorry since I don't understand. I always compile and get the PDF. I work with winedit 5.6

Comment: WinEdt 5.6? That's a very old version. Current version is 10.3. Nevertheless, I suppose  you have a way to choose the compiler in the taskbar.

Comment: Yes it is old but in general I don't find problems in compilations. The only problem is in your answer. My question is unfortunately closed and i cannot receive may be a more simpler answer. Thank you Professor for helping me

Comment: Anyway, I suppose you have a way to launch `xelatex` even with this version?

Comment: I'm sorry my field is Math. I'm beginner in Latex. I never hear about ``xelatex``

Comment: My field  is math too. It gives the possibility to use any font that's on you computer (for text), with a package named `fontspec`.